# How can I filter questions by votes?

Tags: discussion

Is there a way to filter questions by Votes?

I have noticed many times questions are downvoted because they are not very clear, so I thought I could review questions with low votes to see if some could be improved.

However I can't find how to accomplish this, is it possible?

Also I have noticed there seems to be a way to do very advanced filtering, is there an advanced guide on how to filter question on SO?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can't filter by votes but you can by [score](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=1438&tab=votes&q=test%20score%3a-10..0%20answers%3a0%20is%3aq)

You type in the search box:

> test score:-10..0 answers:0 is:q

which means, search for the word `test`, with a score between -10 and 0, with 0 answers and only posts that are a question.

[image: search for votes]

Next to the search button you can expand the *Advanced Search Tips*

There is a [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) about searching

Comment: That's a good rep notification there.

Comment: Yeah, tnx but it includes also MSE rep and that comes easier then SO rep so don't be discouraged @DaniSpringer

Comment: What is MSE? I'm interested :) Btw how do I put my rep together from different sites (if it's possible, and if I won't get shot down for asking this here).

Comment: [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com), the meta for the complete network. If you have more than 200 rep on sites you can visit your [network profile](http://stackexchange.com/users/6910287/dani-springer?tab=reputation)

Comment: Got it and thank you.