# How to search by negative votes

Tags: support, downvotes, search

How do I search by negative votes?

I want to find questions with votes between -4 until -1. I failed to search by "votes: -2"; it returns positive votes number.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: May I ask what are you heading for?

Comment: I wanted to check questions that can be closed and maybe up vote or try to answer before it'll be closed if I think It'll help

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Use the between range operator (lowvalue .. highvalue)

[`score:-4..-1`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=score%3A-4..-1)

By using `score:-2` you'll get posts with a score of -2 and higher, which explains why you also see positive scored posts.

To get posts with only a score of -2 use `score:-2..-2`

To get posts with a score with -2 or less, leave out the lowvalue: `score:..-2`

All the available search options are expalined in the Help Center under [Searching](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) and there is a cheat sheet at the [right-hand side](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295155/578411) of the search result page.

Relevant MSE post: [Add search option for down voted posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/162063/158100)

Comment: so score:-4..-4 will get only -4

Comment: You can omit the starting value, use `score:..-1` to get all negatively scored posts, `score:..-2` for posts with a score of `-2` and lower.

Comment: @MartijnPieters where can I find the documentation of search feature?

Comment: @xenteros: in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/wT7apDH.png

Comment: Also this is really interesting, I wish they'd bring back the tab filters that let me see only +3.. questions.

Comment: Has anything changed recently? I'm searching for [`score:-4..-1`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=score%3A-4..-1) as described, and it's only returning posts with `0` votes.

Comment: @EduardoBaitello yes, there is a test going on that shows downvoted posts as if they have a zero score.

Comment: Thanks @rene. Is there a source where I can refer to be aware of these tests/changes?

Comment: @EduardoBaitello sheer luck and keep an eye on meta, specially new posts from staff: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/390179/578411