# Viewing/sorting questions with the least votes

Tags: feature-request, questions, search, sorting

Going at [`/questions?sort=votes`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes) sorts the question with higher votes.

How can I sort the questions in opposite direction? So to show the questions with the least votes first?

---

I'm aware that I can visit the latest page, but the problem is that it doesn't represent the fixed address, so today it may work (2063rd page), but tomorrow the same link can show the different result. So I'm looking for the straight solution with the fixed link.

Comment: Click the last page at the bottom of the search results?

Comment: @AshleyMedway Yes, it's kind of workaround. I'm looking for some straight solution with fixed address, like adding some reverse parameter in the URL. As today it could be 2063rd page, tomorrow the same link won't work for the last page.

Comment: Why would questions with the least votes be interesting?

Comment: Just checking when I'll hit the badge for [the least voted question](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions?page=18&sort=votes) on the other site (just kidding). For real, I just asking out of the curiosity as nice-to-have feature which I would expect to exist out-of-box.

Comment: Why is it nice to have? Who needs this? For what purpose? If its just for curiosities sake then I say sorting by votes then clicking the last page is more than appropriate. IMO don't waste time developing something that 0.0001% are going to use.

Comment: The same purpose that the users with high-rep have it at [`/tools?tab=stats`](https://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=stats) in order to help with moderation of the site.

Comment: *The same purpose that the users with high-rep have it at /tools* - But don't you have enough rep for that at 37K? In any case you could probably create a query for this in the Stack Exchange Data Explorer.

Comment: Most of the lowest-voted questions are deleted, so this is a lot less interesting than most people think it will be...

Comment: I'm asking for a simple feature request. It is so simple in my mind, that I didn't expect it doesn't exist. Majority of sites and all kind of CMSes have it by default, so what's the reason of not having it? So there are many advanced search commands (_Advanced Search Tips_), but there isn't a way to sort the questions with least votes?

Comment: @kenorb Features are added when there's a compelling reason *for* the feature, where those reasons exceed the cost of implementing the feature.  If you want the feature you need to argue for why it *should* exist, rather than expecting others to tell you why it shouldn't.

Comment: I'm sure there is or would be some reason behind this, same as other sorting features were implemented for some particular reasons. So I wouldn't argue about this now and the costs, I'm not expecting or demanding anything, this is just nice-to-have feature request.

Comment: One of the guiding principles of the site's Q&A - its selling point - is that "good answers rise to the top".  If we allow for an alternate sort to allow us to plumb the depths of a question, we're **rapidly contradicting** the main selling point of the site.

Answer (score -1):

As for workaround, I've found the following [search query](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=score%3A-1000--100) can be useful (as per this [post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/350349/55075)):

```
score:-1000--100
```

Which at least can give the benefits of the fixed address to access the negative questions with certain threshold.

---

Not to mention the mod tools at [`/tools?tab=stats`](https://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=stats) for +10k users which can list the questions with *lowest voted*, but only for particular period (it seems it's limited to maximum of 30 days).

---

Another workaround is to use *[Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/)*, few examples:

- [Most Down-Voted Questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/707025/most-down-voted-questions)
- [Top 100 most downvoted posts](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/628257/top-100-most-downvoted-posts)