# Why can I no longer see that a post has a negative score?

Tags: support, downvotes, voting, a-b-testing

> Thanks for your vote! Your vote has been recorded and it affects this post's ranking. Since this post has reached the minimum score of 0 your vote will not be displayed.

I just downvoted a question posted few days ago which was at 0 votes. After casting my vote I got a blue popup with the above message:

[image: > Thanks for your vote! Your vote has been recorded and it affects this post's ranking. Since this post has reached the minimum score of 0 your vote will not be displayed.]

The vote was recorded and it shows as -1 on my screen. When I opened the same page with my puppet account it also shows as -1, which means it is public and displayed.

What is this message and what does it mean?

Comment: eh, i wouldn't mind that change. but it's rather odd for it to only be half rolled out (if at all.) What good would A/B testing something you cant interact with do?

Comment: I can't reproduce it (neither on meta nor on the main page). But that doesn't mean much, there could be some A/B testing ongoing where only a few users get this message. The text of the message sounds as if votes would be capped at 0 which I wouldn't prefer to happen.

Comment: If the minimum score is 0 then it's just as good as any other question that has zero upvotes, and provides no indication to the community or the asker that there are problems that need to be fixed.

Comment: Possibly related (MSE): [Don't show negative score on questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70566/dont-show-negative-score-on-questions)

Comment: @Dharman the next time this happens please try to capture a screenshot. For the record, I can't seem to get this to work (and I'm very much hoping it isn't something they're seriously considering).

Comment: I came here because I wanted to ask the same thing, but I got *"Thanks for your vote! Your vote has been recorded and it affects this post's ranking. Since this post has reached the minimum score of -1 your vote will not be displayed."* Still, same experience as yours, the score was (and is) properly displayed.

Comment: I've just experienced this! I saw this discussion a day or so ago and I was intrigued. Now, it seems, I've been promoted to the ranks of Guinea Pig! But, in my case, I was on a post that already showed a vote count of (really) **-6**; I added my downvote, then I got the blue pop-up about the minimum level of -1, and the post now shows its vote count as -1 (it very briefly flashed -7, though). Crazy!

Comment: Can this post be featured?

Comment: Seeing a total of -1 but a breakdown of +1/-5 was very confusing. I refreshed the page a dozen times trying to "fix" the vote count. I thought JavaScript was broken or a cache was misbehaving or something.

Comment: MSE: Downvoted but question stayed at zero](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334832/downvoted-but-question-stayed-at-zero)

Comment: I see all negatively scored post as score of 0! But if I expand the vote counts, it displays normally

Comment: Is there any way to opt out of this? Or perhaps a userscript that goes back to the old behavior? Negative scores are incredibly useful for me to see, and masking it as zero to everyone is bizarre to me.

Comment: I guess I'm in a group that sees the questions being shown as 0 when negative... I am not pleased.

Comment: @JeffMercado I know. I cast a 10th negative vote on one post, which I almost never do, and I get a very eerie feeling when going through [tag:mysqli] and seeing all posts at 0, while I know very well they should all be well below zero.

Comment: F... too bad we can't opt out, it is way too distracting. Now it's impossible to find questions that I generally would avoid... Or finding the bad ones wondering "why isn't anyone downvoting this garbage?" I guess this is a sign that I should stay away til this experiment is over

Comment: [Here's a userscript](https://gist.github.com/CertainPerformance/d16147600ffa63691e88116b5b040f1d) which turns the experiment off on question pages, if you want to see true vote totals on pageload and after voting. (if using Tampermonkey, you'll have to enable instant script injection)

Comment: This feels entirely disingenuous not to do the same for upvoted content

Comment: nonono @Sayse "how this bad question can have only -1, let me add my downovte to it" - this is how it will (I hope) work. Especially for users under 1K who will be deprived seeing real negative score. We don't want similar reasoning for positive score questions, don't we. Let them users think "+5 looks good enough already, I''ll pass" :)

Comment: It's wired to see 0 votes on spam post. I don't against but ............................. Any solution for spam flag.

Comment: I started to post a question to ask the same thing as it also happened to me.  And does the asker see the negative votes so they can make a decision whether to delete their question.   But more to the point, where can I find out recent changes to Stack Overflow, even this "A/B" testing of changes.  And it would also be nice to know the philosophy behind it and any other changes.

Comment: How about implementing a [I downvoted because](https://idownvotedbecau.se/) feature. The main reason newcomers feel unwelcome when they get downvotes is because it feels like a personal slight. Force people to give a reason anonymously via drop down and feed this back to OP. Also doesn’t SO website and others want to collect data and statistics on why downvotes are happening?

Comment: new user may not know how to use the internet, or a forum. Standards on SE are high and that's a good thing. But downvotes and duplicate flags an my very first questions on the site without any comments has pushed me away from this site in fear for many years. Even if you understand the rules avoiding downvotes needs practice.

Comment: "what does it mean" It means that Stack is slowly removing the things that made it great in favour of appeasing people who feel offended at things that carry absolutely no offence. As always, the majority going about normal life get covered in the insane blanket policies to cater for the few.

Comment: Is there a way I can stop seeing the pop up?

Comment: @AndrewAllen We tried asking for that and it didn't happen: [Can we incorporate what idownvotedbecau.se is trying to do?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357702/691711).  However, I'll **never** be for removing anonymous voting.  Allow for the dropdown for feedback, but don't let it stand in the way of me voting.

Comment: last week I was getting its the listed message with -1 to say its already -1 its been taken into account but not displayed, today its 0's  problem with zeros is it looks like no ones looked at it, no ones voted when they have.  This seems deceiving as while it could be a very poor question the user is not getting the "shows no effort or generally poor" votes displayed.  While people use a multitude of reasons to downvote, "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful" is the clear text on it and is self explainatory

Comment: Fun fact: I only see zero score for answers with negative scores, but if the score is sufficiently low then the answer is still grayed out.

Comment: The experiment seems to be over now.

Comment: @zero298 agree - it too often leads to retaliation downvotes or arguments

Comment: @AndrewAllen - If I am forced to list the reasons I have issued a downvote, that automated statement that is generated on my behalf will be taken as a personal attack on the user's character, which isn't my fault but when a question is submitted as a question the reason for a downvote is obvious (let alone the grammatical/spelling/formatting) problems that are likely to exist with it. If you want to provide that feedback in such a way, only a moderator can see it (or trusted users with high reputation), I am all for it. I, however, will never support, something that will fuel personal attacks.

Comment: To close/reopen voters: Shog [used this post as a semi-official announcement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390178/why-can-i-no-longer-see-that-a-post-has-a-negative-score/390410#comment733962_390179). It should not be closed.

Answer (score -70, accepted):

We are conducting a two-week experiment to understand how the voting user interface impacts question answering and editing.

- The effects of this experiment are superficial - only the displayed score is affected.
- This applies to questions and answers, to authors and voters and readers; if you're in one of the test groups you'll see it everywhere, if not then you'll see it nowhere.
- You will only see this if you are logged into the site.
- Depending on which experimental group you're in, you may see one of a number of changes to post scores, or no change at all.
- Group membership is assigned by account. Anyone may end up in any group, *and should stay there*.
- You can see the real up/down vote counts at any time by clicking the score while viewing a post - **even if you haven't earned [the Established User privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user)**.
- Search results will render differently too, but score-based operators and sorts work normally (on the actual score)

You will see the user interface revert to normal behavior on October 23rd.

Comment: Comments were getting really long & folks were complaining that they were hard to follow, so I've [moved them to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200664/discussion-on-answer-by-shog9-new-popup-message-when-voting-on-a-question). Feel free to discuss this there (I'll drop in too), but try to reserve comments here for bugs so that I can triage them quickly - thanks!

Comment: No, this was planned months ago @sklivvz. The only connection is that I really dropped the ball on testing because of the other stuff.

Comment: It seems obvious that some of the reason for this testing is to not hurt the OP's feelings when they can't put any effort into a question. So, if SO doesn't want to show the OP the real score, then at least [show them this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0m5H.png).

Comment: This isn't limited to OPs or even guaranteed for OPs, @kdavis; rep effects mean they'll be the least affected.

Comment: If you can't show me which questions need critical attention (i.e. close votes, flags, deletion votes) by showing the number of downvotes, I'm not even going to bother hunting for them.  Enjoy your mess for the next two weeks.

Comment: Was this test announced anywhere? Seems to have come out of the blue again.

Comment: I've been using this post as a clearinghouse for information, @DavidG. In hindsight, would've been better to make an announcement; was preoccupied & missed the opportunity.

Comment: That's completely understandable @Shog9. I'm not sure if I agree with this as a solution to anything, but totally appreciate the testing to see the results and I'm open to changes based on real numbers.

Comment: I'm not down voting if it's already -1. Some questions/answers deserve the -XXX punishment.

Comment: *"and if you switch between multiple machines or browsers you may even end up in multiple groups."* well this explains why I'm seeing this at home and not at work today.

Comment: In foresight, to avoid further churn: please be more careful about such experiments and sudden changes. No need to amplify the anger and frustration that currently leaks out of MSE and MSO all day long.

Comment: Heard loud and clear, @GhostCat

Comment: Got a fix in the works for that @Larnu. Will update shortly. **[update: FIXED!]**

Comment: I must admit that seeing wrong number of votes is very frustrating. It feels like SO is lying to me. Not only the top managers but the whole system.

Comment: @Shog9 What are these "groups"? I'm not noticing the experiment at all anymore.

Comment: Then you're in the baseline group, @jl2210 - and should stay there for the duration.

Comment: Great, another 'method' of forcing a 'welcoming' environment by hiding negative feedback on bad questions. Which result in alienating the existing community.

Comment: I don't appreciate being lying το, even for (poorly designed) experimental purposes, however well-meant they may be; you don't like downvotes to be shown, I am suspending all voting and moderating activities. Good luck...

Comment: It's only an experiment right now guys, you probably need to calm down a little. If the results of the test are positive, then what's the problem?

Comment: @DavidG you mean - what's the problem if the test "proves" that it is "better" (by what *objective*, exactly?) not to show the negative scores to anyone, misleading everyone who looks at a post that it is just a zero-score one, while in reality it may be at -X? I don't know, don't you see any problem?

Comment: @desertnaut Why should you care what the vote count is? Do you vote based on existing counts? If so, that's pretty bad practice. You should vote based on content, not what the number on the left says, it should be completely irrelevant. There seems to be a lot of hyperbole around right now, I know why, but let's try to keep our heads here, that's all I'm saying.

Comment: @DavidG please be reasonable; I don't need to see scores in order to *vote*, I need to see scores in order to decide to which posts I will devote my (precious) time trying to help; and by downvoting I intend to send this useful signal to others in a similar situation, something already expressed here by others (see [LittleBobbyTables comment above](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390178/new-popup-message-when-voting-on-a-question-answer/390179#comment733926_390179)). If I should not care about it, as you imply, then [why is voting important?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)

Comment: @DavidG I do sometimes vote based on what others have voted. Not like a sheep following the majority, but if an answer is better than another, and the other already has more votes, I'll only upvote the one I think is better. If an answer is poor (not in need of deletion tho) but it already has what I consider to be enough downvotes, I will likely not bother.

Comment: Maybe I missed a memo or other discussions, but this is crazyness. I get it, it's a trial, sometimes face value isn't enough :) but one of the good things of Stack sites is we can see bad answers and exactly how bad they are. An answer with -1 vs an answer with -21 is a vast difference. I'd steer clear most times of the latter, whereas -1 I might read it and see if there's anything useful (as somtimes the net result is not a good representative, but being able to see that always is another debate..)

Comment: @desertnaut voting is important. You shouldn't care what score the post have *right now*. Also, I don't get why seeing an accurate vote would help you to decide how to invest your time, since search actually takes the backend score. Search is better for people looking for questions to answer, so maybe your methodology wasn't efficient enough.

Comment: @james And I'm sure you will see the scores after a certain amount of time has passed, the point of this is to see if it mitigates the "pile on" effect, and alienates new users. If an answer is - 21 a day later, I'm sure it will show as - 21. But my point still stands, people just need to take a step back and realise this isn't the disaster they think it is.

Comment: @desertnaut I'm confused. You say you don't need to see votes to vote, then specifically say you need to see votes to vote. Also, see my previous comment.

Comment: I also fear this might lead to more *unintented* "pile on" downvotes, rather than curtailing bandwagon voting. Just stumbled across a few that already had more than the sufficient -2, where I wouldn't normally have voted on. So this test might impair a fairer vote distribution already. // As for not detering  new users, something like Ghosty Spooktober (no profiles and reputation shown) might be more worthwhile as followup experiment.

Comment: @DavidG didn't say that, please read more closely (the existing scores and *my* downvotes are independent); and I do take a step back and stop here...

Comment: I absolutely cannot see the point of lying to your users about their downvotes. Or to other users either.

Comment: I don't think the experiment is impacting the data explorer, or is it? Is it true that in the last two weeks lots of questions did not get any vote at all (much more than usual)?

Comment: This change makes it much harder to signal that the content of a given "answer" is wrong, and possibly shouldn't be used because it's wrong, contains errors, has nothing to do with the question, doesn't solve the problem, or possibly even introduces new bugs and errors by promoting malpractices. Now zero-point answers must be seen as the new `-3`, regardless of whether they are actually 0 or not.

Comment: "...question answering and editing." I'm concerned about the fact that there's no consideration for how it affects how readers *use* a post as a source of information. As I mentioned in my answer, this is an important signal to *readers* who will not participate in either of those activities and who represent the core purpose of SO's existence. I don't know how you could measure the effect I'm talking about, but that effect seems vastly more important than answering and editing.

Comment: I don't know how to measure that effect either, @jpmc26. I suspect doing so would require much, much more than a 2-week test.

Comment: I'm sorry for being harsh, but this is the dumbest $#&* I have ever seen or heard. I'll be back on the 23 October. Not a day earlier, at least not for any productive work here.

Comment: Either you're being hyperbolic, or you've missed a lot. Either way, enjoy your time away!

Comment: @Shog9 any *slight*, however *remote* possibility that Andreas (and others...) *might* have *some* point here, has possibly crossed your mind? Just asking (because you don't sound like)...

Comment: I'm not sure what Andreas point was, other than that this is dumb. I kinda disagree with that. Lots of other folks have raised very good points though; I'm looking forward to seeing how well y'all have ended up predicting the outcome. @desertnaut

Comment: @Shog9 predicting the outcome is none of our business, nor something anyone here really tries to do, especially since the *specific objectives* have not been explicitly disclosed...

Comment: None the less, folks have proposed quite a lot of ways in which this could go horribly wrong... Or at very least, be counter-productive. Regardless of intent, that's useful.

Comment: @Shog9 True, but if you wanted "very good points" and useful feedback, you could have *asked* your community before proceeding (without even announcing it).

Comment: Maybe I want it *all*, @desertnaut - the cake, and the eating thereof.

Comment: @Shog9 well, if you are not joking, the fact that you may feel *entitled* for something like that, sounds somewhat worrisome in itself... :(

Comment: @Shog9 BTW, I'm still waiting for your kind reply, especially since the [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390343/ethical-considerations-of-the-ongoing-experiment-re-not-displaying-negative-scor) has now reached a net positive score (from -10 yesterday), and Makoto has just offered his opinion, and not actually any answer.

Comment: You're reading a bit too much into it then, @desertnaut. I neither expected nor demanded such feedback, but since it has been freely offered I would be quite the ingrate if I did not pay attention and make the most of it.

Comment: @Shog9 maybe I am indeed, but with comments like the cake one... you don't help very much! :)

Comment: If the end result is no longer displaying negative total votes I assume that this fact would be included in the basic tour. If so it might be a more accurate test to include the character ≤ before the score when it is at minimum value since it conveys the same information. Would also assuage some complains. Is it too late to restart the test?

Comment: It is, @jose - I'd much prefer to keep this as short as possible, and restarting now would necessarily extend it.

Comment: it would be nice if those of us in groups (I was in -1 last week Im in 0 this week) got to give feedback on what we thought at the end of the week or something

Comment: Post your thoughts in an answer here at the end of the week, or shoot an email if you prefer - I'll collect them & pass them along to the team @bug!

Comment: It's also a bit weird that the comment is still greyed out when the criteria is met, because the votes show "0".

Comment: Stupid questions maybe, but **when** was this experiment announced? and **when** is it going to end?

Comment: Oct 7 & 23 respectively, @MrUpsidown (took us a couple days to work out bugs)

Comment: So far the only concrete result of this seems to be massive down voting of posts that would otherwise not get as many down votes. Many people tend to feel bad to pile on further down-voting when the post is already at some -5, but now you don't notice it. So instead of "your post is bad and you probably got the message", we now do "your post is bad so therefore we will completely destroy all of your rep". How is that making the site more welcoming?

Comment: @Shog9 how are you collecting data / feedback on the results of this experiment? It's all well and good to say _"it's just an experiment"_ but how (apart from the adding to the currently 97 downvotes on this answer) do we, the community ensure our concerns are heard?

Comment: I started in the -1 group, now Im in the 0 group and all I find is that Im wishing I was in neither..  When does this madness end?

Comment: I'm listening here, and there's also a chatroom linked above, @phil.

Comment: On the 23rd, @Bug

Comment: @Shog9 so the idea was just to drop this on us unannounced and wait for reports of weird behaviour to come rolling in? Doesn't feel like a particularly effective method of conducting an experiment.

Comment: I hope you will also check for a longer-term effect: the decrease of activity of competent people being expelled by the resulting terrible flood of crap content.

Comment: Can you (the company) please consider announcing such experiments in future?

Comment: Is the person who's question it is supposed to see the actual number of votes or not?

Comment: Depends on where they are in the test, @script

Comment: @Shog9 sorry, I'm not following. I'm seeing a 0 on a question of mine which is +3/-5 so I'm wondering if it's working as intended.

Comment: That just means you're in one of the test groups, @Script47

Comment: @Shog9 oh, I thought I remembered reading somewhere that OP would see the actual results of the voting? Is that not the case?

Comment: Downvoting because I feel that hiding negative scores is bad and the notification message is bad and because there was no mention of a test being run before hand, and because I searched regular-meta for this topic first and it wasn't there, further indexing my confusion. I do not think the test is having the hoped-for result.

Comment: Actually, if you really want to make things more friendly, allow us to downvote comments so that users won't feel so attacked when people post rude comments because the rude comments will show a negative score.

Comment: I like that idea, @mchid. But almost entirely irrelevant in this context.

Comment: It's October 23 already, and I am still seeing this.

Comment: Not in my timezone it isn't, @pppery

Comment: @Shog9 When are the results going to be announced? And [don't say 6 to 8 weeks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/390721/10795151).

Comment: 6-8... Fortnights? @jl2210. But seriously, I don't know - got a meeting next week to review, will proceed from there.

Comment: Please do this on meta and MSE

Comment: Finally this UI nightmare is over. And hopefully it will never come back.

Answer (score 165):

Is there a way to opt out of this experiment?

Questions like this:

> [image]

Really should be deleted ASAP. They're just *"Write my code for me"* dumps, and basically lying to your readers about the question's actual vote count isn't helping.

Especially relevant here is the fact that some features are locked behind the question's score, such as the ability to [delete a closed question that's at score `-3`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user):

> [image]

I didn't realize I could delete that question until I realized this experiment was running and decided to check the score...

If anything, turn this off for users that have 1000+ rep. As [established user](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user), you get to see vote counts, any way.

---

Now that I know this experiment affects my account, I immediately installed [CertainPerformance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/9515207/certainperformance)'s [userscript](https://gist.github.com/CertainPerformance/d16147600ffa63691e88116b5b040f1d) that automatically fetches the correct vote count.

Comment: You say "this experiment affects my account..." Does it? How? Because if it affects your account, then it probably affects mine - so I'd like to know!

Comment: @Adrian: In other words: It appears to be active for my account. I see incorrect vote counts on questions.

Comment: OK! I thought you meant it actually impacted your rep, or some such. For example, when I get the blue pop-up and it says, "because its reached the minimum … your vote won't be counted" (or whatever) I thought maybe my downvote wouldn't impact my rep score, as normal.

Comment: Ah no, not that I can see.

Comment: Yes, but it is very annoying: seeing all posts with (big) negative scores showing as zero, unless I click to see the actual vote counts! Eg, here's one where +20 - 63 = 0: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20875614/why-wont-clang-compile-this-source-code-that-works-in-vs2012

Comment: @Adrian: for me, the votes are actually showing `-1` now, if I disable that userscript.

Comment: So we have a two-tiered-test! Some folks get a -1 limit, others get a zero limit. (Maybe there are other groups, too?)

Comment: As Shog said: *It's an A/B/C test*

Comment: @CertainPerformance - it does not seem to take on my Chrome on OSX Catalina

Comment: @mplungjan The userscript? Any console errors, or do some things work or some don't, or..? The userscript depends on instant script injection, did you turn that on? (or, is there even an option for that in the OSX version? There is one Windows-Chrome TM. Without instant script injection, things get a lot harder)

Comment: I added it to extensions as documented. I see `Error in event handler: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCurrent' of undefined
    at e (chrome-extension://lhdoppojpmngadmnindnejefpokejbdd/adapter.bundle.js:124:422529)` in the console

Comment: The opt-out feature should be in a link directly in that message. Of all the recent changes to SO, this a strong contender for the most unnecessary one.

Answer (score 55):

Well, it appears that I am in the **zero group** and I am solidly not enjoying what I am looking at because it makes my general maintenance routine much harder to conduct.

Most of my time on SO lately has been predominately on my mobile phone.  For me to get the true vote tally on any post, I need to set my phone's browser to Desktop mode (my Samsung phone likes to do me the favor of reverting to Mobile mode whenever it can) to make the vote tally clickable, then click on each (zero) posts' vote tally to see the true score.

I make a habit of reviewing all posts on a page that I visit.

- If a post has not be downvoted, but should be (by my personal set of criteria), I take one for the team and downvote it.  This is mostly about caring for future researchers and  the ultimate goal of curating exceptional SO content.
- If a post is downvoted, but does not deserve to be, I feel it is my responsibility to neutralize the downvote (or play my part in repairing a post that has multiple downvotes).  I have different standards for posts that "shouldn't have a negative vote tally" versus "should be positively voted" (I shall not digress).  This is a matter of "caring" for the poster and future researchers.
- If a post is rightfully downvoted and the page would benefit from its deletion, I also cast my delete vote.  I consider this a necessary duty to exercise.

My only other indications are:

1. If a post is downvoted, the grey "delete" hyperlink appears under the post between "edit" and "flag".
2. If an answer has a -3 or worse tally, the entire post is dimmed.

Since these visual cues are less common, my eye is not yet accustomed to spotting #1, and #2 is seldom engaged.

---

If I am searching SO with `[php] is:answer score:..-1` I have no way of hunting for the worst of the worst in the resulting list.  (I've never bothered to perform this search before today, but my observation remains true.)

---

Consideration other users who seek to neutralize unwarranted downvotes on MY answers.  If other users consider a post of mine to unworthy of downvotes and they prefer to combat the downvoter by upvoting, they cannot easily see if this tactic is necessary without clicking the vote count.

---

I think I'd rather be in the "negative one group" if forced to be in any of them because this gives me more valuable information instantly without extra interactions from me.

---

p.s. I guess this page at least clears up why my downvoted answers are showing up as 0 in the vote tally when I load the page.  This would have been good to know when I was crafting my email to SO headquarters to analyze the suspected voting abuse on pages where I've posted in the last 30 days.

Comment: For mobile: if you scroll down to the footer, there should be a "full site" link - this sets a cookie that will give you a responsive version of the full site, without needing your browser to ask for it. This needs to be done once per-site, but should persist indefinitely.

Comment: @Shog9: yes, but changing the interface to "full site" has other issues. Why isn't it possible to just allow expanding the vote tally in the mobile interface? The fact that you can't see expanded tallies has been an annoyance for a while, but this experiment makes it even more annoying.

Comment: We're hoping to eventually retire the mobile site entirely, and rely on a slimmed-down version of the responsive site @rici. That would make maintaining these pages a *lot* less costly and error-prone. I would strongly recommend using the responsive site and reporting problems you encounter while doing so - it'll pay off much more in the long run than trying to back-port stuff to the mobile site.

Comment: Speaking of, @Shog9 I've noticed lately (like, two months now) that *scrolling* is an issue on mobile and I have to scroll a lot/fast in order to not have it autoscrolled back up on me (or down, if I was going up). I'll grant that my touchscreen is a bit wonky these days, but its *only* Stack Overflow that has this problem (and a select handful of sister sites, not the whole network). But its just...inconsistent enough that I've not bothered whining about it.

Comment: Post a bug report please @draco? Screen-grab if you can.

Comment: @Shog9 "Screen grab" is difficult on mobile. I'll see about trying, though.

Comment: @Shog9 The behavior might've gone away on its own, too. Just spent a good while trying to get it to happen, but couldn't. Maybe it was fixed already or it fixed itself. I don't browse SO regularly on my tablet, and its one of those things that when its working right, you don't notice. Soo... :\

Answer (score 35):

Displaying all negative scores as 0, in my opinion, deprives all users (readers, askers, and answerers) of an important indicator of quality of the post. I downvoted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58343705/1394393) not only because it was Unclear, but also because there was no way to answer it directly without creating a major security vulnerability and because providing a secure alternative implementation would be Too Broad (requiring not only a lot of details missing in the post but also writing significant amounts of code involving several components of their specific application). Downvotes are an important mechanism for alerting readers that there is some kind of problem with the post and triggering some further investigation into why they should be wary about following its advice if they do not already immediately see the reasons why. (The latter case is common if you're searching for an answer. You are not likely to understand the security implications of a line of code unless you are already familiar with all of its components.) Creating security problems is one such reason, and while we have comments to point out such issues, the vote count is vastly more prominent and noticeable, even before the post is read. Imperfect as it may be at doing so, I believe that removing before implementing a replacement to be undermining our ability to indicate such issues.

Displaying them as -1 removes all indication of scale of agreement that there is a problem with the post, but how big an issue that is is debatable. I believe it's a rather major problem, as posts with large numbers of downvotes typically have more major problems.

Zeroing out also seems to be taking things much further than described in the 
[previous blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/07/18/building-community-inclusivity-stack-overflow/) which emphasized a "piling on" effect. Rather than deal with that, this eliminates a major source of negative feedback entirely. I had expected something more along the lines of hiding actual negative scores behind a single, scoreless indicator, which at least preserves some indication of negative feedback without revealing dozens or hundreds of downvotes. That would have similar effects as -1, although it would be much more straightforward for those viewing the post.

Answer (score 30):

IMHO, this experiment is likely to produce biassed observations, because the behavior of downvoters is different depending on the score of questions and/or answers they are likely to downvote.

Not showing negative scores is likely to cause even more negative votes because voters are more likely to express negativity if no one has already.

Not showing negative scores, or flooring the score to -1 removes useful information from casual readers, namely that reading an answer is likely a waste of time, see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70570/285279).

If the goal is to limit negativity, make the negative votes nominative, just like the close votes and the delete action:

> Here is a proposal to make negative votes more informative for the poster: you could mandate an informative comment or a reference to an existing one (eg: this question was downvoted because *it is off topic as it calls for personal opinions*, this answer was downvoted because of syntax errors...). A downvote would trigger a popup and request an explanatory comment, which obviously would be signed, and deleting the comment would remove the downvote.

Furthermore, any edit on a downvoted post should appear in the downvoter's inbox for review. More generally, modified posts could trigger the inbox of all users that have commented the post.

Comment: Don't get why you were downvoted! The fact is that I now need to downvote every bad answer that stands seemingly at -1 even though it was -10 because *I would not know* if it has sufficient amount of votes for swift deletion / to be not shown on the front page...

Comment: I would also **really** like to know if this experiment has any impact on perceived "sympathy upvotes".  Every now and then I see upvotes on content that would never be considered "useful" by community standards and they usually only happen on questions with negative score.  I wonder if there is a way to determine if this change would affect that behavior.

Comment: On the other hand flooring the vote a 0 will make pity upvotes much more unlikely.

Comment: Flooring the vote tally at 0 makes neutralizing unwarranted downvotes much more unlikely.

Comment: You make a good point, and I think the results you suggest are exactly what @shog9 is trying to test the validity of

Answer (score 22):

Is this experiment related to the desire to have SE sites feel less hostile to newcomers?

If so, then make this the default ONLY for the people below a certain score threshold. I believe most people who have been around a long time, would prefer to see the actual score.

@Shog9 - Re editing: I used to try and improve answers. I've long since given that up - too often it is not appreciated by the original answerer, even though I explain why in comments - and hopefully have gotten better at maintaining a neutral-POV. Unless SO makes a clear policy statement that people don't "own" their answers - and go back to Jeff's original statement "If you can improve an answer, then do so" - I'm not going to touch people's "precious" answers.

Comment: Don't worry -- we appreciate edits to answers, we just don't express that appreciation. Nobody except Stack Exchange really owns the answers, so please feel free to edit.

Comment: @JL2210 - I'm saying that without an *explicit policy that everyone can see*, and that I can point to, it isn't worth it to me to deal with the responses that I have sometimes gotten in the recent past. I'm certain that there are others with a similar experience. (Years ago, this was less of an issue - could point to a post Jeff made in meta.)

Comment: People below an arbitrarily determined threshold of rep points deserve to see the truth too.  Good or bad, the truth is vital in steering our thinking and actions.

Comment: @mickmackusa - oh I totally agree. I'm baffled by why this experiment is even being attempted, so was blindly guessing at what could be the purpose - and offering a "compromise" if that was the case.

Comment: I could understand a negative cap of three. Anything beyond -3 is needless "pile on" -- the public opinion is just as clear at -3 as it is at -10. There is the Peer Pressure badge to consider here too.  So I think once a post reaches -3, it is safe to modify the vote tally to a static exression: `<=-3` (no, that is not some rude emoticon referring to the poster though a correlation could be inferred; it literally means "less than or equal to negative three".

Comment: @mickmackusa _"the public opinion is just as clear at -3 as it is at -10"_ Disagree. The -1000 score on recent staff posts is extremely useful information for everybody involved.

Comment: I'm speaking in terms of what is showing without clicking the vote tally and what is necessary/relevant to readers at a glance -- not actually limiting the DVs.  If you think excessive pile on is important on meta/opinion-based sites, then fine don't cap the tallies there.  I assume the goal is to make posters feel less embarrassed via public perception when they post something "bad". If you think it is important for the staff (or anyone) to be embarrassed/hurt, then definitely continue to permit voting to be used as a shaming weapon.

Answer (score 16):

I find the current experimental behavior disorienting at best, unproductive at worst.

Maybe I'm not the intended audience, but given that I now have known about this for a week, all the change does is get in my way. I can usually tell just by looking at question and the number of comments under it, what its vote count likely actually is. In any sort of search, view count, title, and post summary give me much the same information.

The new user interface behavior hasn't, as near as I can tell, changed my own behavior in any material way. I have already voted on a question before I click to see what the actual vote count is, and I'm voted based on the content, not the vote count.

The one exception *maybe* is that there's a small possibility I'm *more* likely to downvote a post now. In the past, if I saw a post in the list that had a lot of downvotes, sometimes I'd think to myself "well, looks like the Community has already done a good job moderating that bad question away" and leave it alone. Those posts are no longer overlooked by me, and so might now get a downvote from me that it otherwise would not have.

Between this and the previous experiment, I feel like there's been a new movement toward pseudo-scientific attempts to learn things. The desire to learn things is good, but I feel that the actual process being used is poorly-informed and largely self-fulfilling.

Answer (score 14):

So the site becomes more of a social network with the concept of having likes without dislikes... That's disappointing and not constructive: this is content-oriented site, people downvote here not because they are hostile to somebody, but for a reason of the content quality. It's almost never personal to the OP, I estimate personal bias downvotes as well below 1%, maybe even below 0.1%, especially among established users. If the OP feels hurt, that's he who should understand that downvotes don't mean that anybody intended to hurt him, but his question/answer needs improvement or gives a bad (hurtful) advice. So if you feel that you need a change here, better add some explanation to the newcomers that downvotes are not evil and not a personal attack at all.

Answer (score 8):

So, to sum it up, there are three groups that each user is put in at random:

- the "baseline group" -- this is the behavior that you would normally expect.
- the "negative one group" -- the vote count shown on posts for users in this group is capped at negative one.
- the "zero group" -- like the above, but instead of negative one the displayed vote count is capped at 0.

Each and every user can view the actual vote totals on a post by clicking the post's score -- regardless of having earned the ["Established User privilege"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user) or not.

Answer (score 0):

This seems "mostly harmless" for questions: a bad question is usually just a bit of an annoyance, but maybe this prevents people from piling on, avoids drawing too much attention to "car-crashes in progress" and possibly means people don't vote based on what others have done (either "with" or "against").

For answers this seems more dubious: some answers are downvoted because they give genuinely harmful advice (e.g. open up enormous security holes). Therefore hiding voting information on answers may end up hiding a useful warning signal.

Therefore, if you do adopt something like this more permanently in future I'd encourage you to consider treating questions and answers differently.

---

This is kind of what @jpmc26 said in [their answer to this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/390410/4657412), but I really just wanted to emphasise the difference between questions and answers here.

Comment: I agree, hiding negative scores has more potential for far reaching negative effects on answers. IMO, doing so on answers largely invalidates the quality controls which SO's success is built upon. A major point of SO is that a visitor can see what solutions other people found to be good, *and* what solutions other people found to be bad (and how bad), along with ones on which feedback is neutral. If no negative scores are shown to users, then users are unable to differentiate between "unknown/neutral" and bad. That causes all sorts of problems, culminating in a *much* less useful site.

Answer (score -9):

Generally I agree with the idea behind this change from the perspective of making the site feel less harsh to users who aren't acquainted with the way SO works, but... it's so jarring. The banner popping up with every vote is annoying, so I adblocked that, and then when I'm viewing questions/answers that should be downvoted that don't appear to be only to realize after voting myself that they actually were, yet another confusing situation.

It needs some polishing. I'm not quite sure yet what would help make it less jarring/confusing. Maybe making it toggleable so that powerusers can turn it off?

Comment: If the idea was to make Stack Overflow appear "nice," it would have been adequate enough to have it apply only to anonymous users or low rep. Instead, they opted to throw everyone into Neverland.

Comment: The conflict i have is there's certainly some "powerusers" who complain too much imo about receiving downvotes. Hiding the fact that their own post is downvoted IMO is beneficial, for the same reason hiding it from new users is, it would reduce friction.