# Why are vote totals not correctly summing?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, voting, user-experience

I revisited a question I downvoted and was surprised by the (relatively) high vote count. Expanding the votes showed that there were 5 downvotes and no upvotes, even though the total is listed as -1.

[image: question total of negative one with components of zero upvotes and five downvotes]

Another user saw a different total for the same question:

[image: question total of zero]

And also noted the same for an answer:

[image: answer total of zero]

[image: answer components of zero upvotes and three downvotes]

Comment: This is an interesting test, but this kind of test should be announced to the impacted users...

Comment: Hiding useful signal to be superficially nicer to people the signal was aimed for.

Comment: Looks like you found C ;-)

Comment: @DenysSéguret As an A/B(/C) test, that would defeat a large part of the purpose.

Comment: @TylerH but we can see the result anyway. We *know* the sum.

Comment: @DenysSéguret See here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390178/new-popup-message-when-voting-on-a-question

Comment: this is very bad .. I consider the score of the question before looking at it and now I cannot know if it's a bad one or not ...

Comment: @TemaniAfif I can't speak for SO, but I'd guess that would be a goal of the experiment. Now you would be more likely to look at it and potentially participate (vote it up/down, edit, answer) when you wouldn't have before.

Comment: I sillt won't for questions having -7 that are clearly off topic. Now I will waste my time to look at those questions where I will simply cast another (now useless) downvote.

Comment: I refreshed the page a dozen times trying to "fix" the vote count. I thought JavaScript was broken or something. Very confusing.

Comment: @TemaniAfif do you look at -1 questions too?

Comment: @Druckles it depends, sometimes I have only few times to check questions so I bypass all the negative ones even the -1 and focus only on the <=0 considering the fact that they will be  more intresting. When I have more time I look into negative ones to see what is going on. Now by having all of them at 0 I have no clue about the *potential* intresting ones and I may waste a lot of times.

Comment: @TemaniAfif there are arguably some potential [ethical](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390343/ethical-considerations-of-the-ongoing-experiment-re-not-displaying-negative-scor) considerations here, including for the reasons you state