# Good to see improvements happening in the core product!

Tags: discussion, user-experience

I would like to commend the team at the mothership for their recent renewed activity vis-à-vis the core product. After the many years of <strike>neglect</strike> concentrating on other adventures which didn’t always pan out, it’s good to see [some](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/381671/476) [actual](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/390887/476) [improvement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388313/476) in the core Q&A engine again. After the tweaking and fixing of existing stuff, perhaps one may even hope for some new features?

Even if this is all happening amongst a host of controversies; maybe not *every* step being taken is in the right direction yet, but it’s good to see that steps *are* being taken at all. There’s clearly a renewed push to *do something*. I’m optimistic that it’ll eventually average out to an improved experience; along the lines of breaking some eggs to make an omelette. Just be careful which eggs to break.

If you share my feelings and would like to give some positive encouragement, leave it below.

Comment: To me it falls into the *not useful* category, I'm not even sure what it's meant to discuss. I see no reason to close-vote it but DV seemed reasonable. I'm not even entirely sure what features we're meant to be celebrating here.

Comment: @ivarni I can sympathise with the not-sure-what-this-is-for reason; but there have been a lot of protest posts recently which are more announcements than discussions, so this kind of post isn't that unusual in the grand scheme of things. I thought I'd simply post something positive for a change instead. Feature-wise I'm talking about things like the new question wizard, doing experiments with vote counts and reputation points, and redesigned message banners. SE Inc. is clearly playing around with the core formula, trying to eke out a better experience.

Comment: @deceze I can absolutely see the need for some positivity in all the negativity. A lot of stuff has been blown way out of proportion. I just thought this post was more on the confusing side.

Comment: @ivarni I've actually been hesitating to post this for a few days now, exactly because of concerns that it won't fit, that's it's unusual etc. I've just come to the conclusion that that's exactly the wrong thing to do. No wonder SE staff is reluctant to look at Meta if people are hesitant to post this kind of post.

Comment: I'm not sure those A/B tests are a positive thing. For the rest: Yay!

Comment: @Cerbrus Not sure how else you'd go forward with any *substantial* changes to the platform except A/B test them and gather a lot of data. But regardless, I'll reiterate that I'm happy to see *any* movement at all. If A/B tests aren't working well for some reason, SE will hopefully figure that out and come up with other strategies. Almost *any* sort of iteration is good at this point.

Comment: Oh, I mean the subject matter of those specific tests.

Comment: @Cerbrus yeah, the voting hiding just spurned *a lot* of confusion overall. I'm not sure how useful it was as an A/B test when it got so much publicity. The new one with close notices seems it's better, since it was actually announced and there is now an official way to collect bug reports - with the votes, people were confused which was a bug and which was intended. There was hardly a guide on this matter aside from saying it's currently an experiment. And the goal wasn't very clear, so community feedback on the feature was...random. Should users give feedback? What feedback is expected?

Comment: At any rate, there are *finally* things being done and looked at. After more than 6-8 weeks of waiting but better late than never. So, I upvoted to agree that it's good.

Comment: @VLAZ Well, one good thing about the Voting A/B test was that it showed how many people actually do look and rely on it. I got the impression the "confused" responses surprised Shog and triggered a bit of thought :-)

Comment: I'm really looking forward to the new close dialogue. I spend nearly half of my time here closing questions and currently that isn't really fun (especially searching for dupes). If I spend less time closing ...

Comment: @CindyMeister motivation for voting A-B experiment has been [explained here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/390414/839601) and to me it reads as attempt to collect data allowing to keep rejecting flood of complaints about negative scores. "I've been fielding complaints from folks regarding downvoted posts for many, many years now... Our response to those complaints has generally been some variation on, "nuh-uh!" And I'm concerned this has started to wear a bit thin. It's time we listened and, with as little disruption as possible, tried to collect some actual data on all of this..."

Comment: @Jonas Wilms: Don't give up! We need you. Are you building [some kind of resource](http://pmortensen.eu/EditOverflow/_Wordlist/EditOverflowList_2019-11-01.html), like FAQs for tags or subjects?

Comment: Thanks for having the courage to post this. I hope they continue to improve the actual Q&A sites.

Comment: @gnat You misunderstand what I was saying. In that long comment "tail" at some point Shog expressed doubt that people would even notice the experiment was taking place (thus, no announcement) and was a bit surprised when someone actually did notice and asked about it in Meta. Subsequently, two or three inquiries turned up almost daily. IOW people pay more attention to and rely on votes than he may have expected.

Comment: I wasn't particularly surprised that folks *noticed*, @cindy - we built in notices, after all... But, I was surprised by rather a lot of other things related to the experiment. Particularly notable lesson: don't do grouping based on IP when most of the folks affected will be logged in and jarred by changing groups!

Answer (score 30):

I'd like to highlight a few points that I especially like about the recent changes:

- They were announced here on Meta, and not on *another castle* (the blog).
- They were announced when development started, and feedback was incorporated along the road.
- They are based on experiments, so the changes can be *proven* right.

Generally, it feels like the community is *involved* in these changes directly *affecting* the community. That's a great thing.