# Different post notices from different machines

Tags: bug, status-completed, close-reasons, closed-questions, a-b-testing

This is the post notice I see from my home machine:

[image]

And this is the post notice I see from my work machine for the same question:

[image]

According to my understanding, this should not happen; from the [Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390887/new-post-notices-closed-on-hold-etc-rolling-out-on-stack-overflow):

> it will only be seen by 50% of users, with the other 50% of users continuing to see the old notices.

And from the [MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337013/new-post-notices-rollout-on-stack-overflow):

> **I still see the old notices and I would rather see the new ones**
>
> *OR*
>
> **I see the new notices and would rather keep the old notices**
>
> During our initial launch period the new post notices (and all related
>   changes) are being shown to 50% of users. There is no easy way to
>   switch between the group of users seeing old or new notices.

Nevertheless, it is apparent that I am seeing both, depending on the machine I happen to work on.

Bug?

Comment: @yivi thanks, but the relevant Meta posts clearly mention users, not sessions

Comment: It does clearly mention users, and since the change I have *only* seen the new banners, so i've either been really lucky or it's user based (or based on some combination of both user and machine etc.)

Comment: I know, [but it's not the case](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337013/new-post-notices-rollout-on-stack-overflow/337038?noredirect=1#comment1121390_337038). I've been on groups A and B on the same machine at different times of the day.

Comment: @yivi does this make it *not* a bug? Have you reported it and received feedback?

Comment: I believe it's by design, hence not a bug. Since I'm not privy to their testing methodology, it's all I have to go with. I know I'm not the only one to have experienced this, so it does seem to be intentional.

Comment: @yivi OK, let's wait for someone to response and clarify, instead of speculating (to be honest, I don't think it's by design, but that's just my belief based on what I read).

Comment: The fact that it says "it will only be seen by 50% of the users" does not mean that the A/B groups are set by user **accounts**. It can also be interpreted that at any given time, 50% of users on the site will be on one group or the other. Which tallies with what I and others like you experienced.

Comment: @desertnaut The groups are presumably *supposed* to be by accounts, but this has been an issue in prior A/B tests, see [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390178/why-can-i-no-longer-see-that-a-post-has-a-negative-score/390179#390179) answer: *"Anyone may end up in any group, and should stay there."*, however note the 10th and 11th revisions: *"if you switch between multiple machines or browsers you may even end up in multiple groups."* and that was later redacted with the note *"FINALLY this should be fixed."*

Comment: @NickAthePopcornKing so, the question holds, right?

Comment: I'd say so, and I'd say it's still a bug, as it *should* be by account, but isn't

Comment: @yivi several counter-arguments here; but, what about simply waiting for someone to respond, instead of engaging in beliefs and possible interpretations?

Comment: per my reading of [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390974/good-to-see-improvements-happening-in-the-core-product#comment738785_390974), IP impacted the group in the experiment: "Particularly notable lesson: don't do grouping based on IP when most of the folks affected will be logged in and jarred by changing groups!"

Comment: @gnat thanks, but as I said, let's wait for an official answer, instead of trying to navigate through all this labyrinth of comments on various threads, which additionally are open to different guesses, readings, and interpretations.

Comment: Experiment has graduated now, so this should no longer happen.

Answer (score 3):

From [a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391063/different-post-notices-from-different-machines#comment739047_391063):

> It's not a bug, the A/B tests are not "user" based but session/ip based. I got different notices on my phone and on desktop at the same time, for example.

I would argue strongly<sup>*</sup>, that this *is* a bug, even if it is by design.

Exposing the same cohort to both versions of an A/B test will invalidate the results.

As a simple example, I was just trying review the new close-vote reasons, and due to the fact that my current session is now in the "control group", I clicked through half a dozen questions trying to find the new close reasons, before I searched Meta to see if the changes had been rolled back. That's when I found this post.

Of course I don't know which specific metrics SE is monitoring to determine the success of the changes, and number of page views may not be in their list, but there's no doubt that the confusion brought on by bouncing users between cohorts will lead to unpredictable behavior, that may skew results for either variant to appear either more negative or more positive than reality.

---

<sup>*</sup>My main experience with A/B testing was working on the A/B testing infrastructure at Booking.com for hotel-facing experiments, which is naturally a different problem space, and maybe SE's data scientists have adequately examined this and come to the conclusion that this somehow won't pollute their data set. But this sort of uncontrolled cohort definition would be the first thing to invalidate an A/B test where I've worked before.