# Did Stack Exchange cut the number of negative comments nearly in half between the beginning of the fourth quarter of 2019 and January 21, 2020?

Tags: discussion, comments, statistics, welcoming

[Franck Dernoncourt](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/7654/franck-dernoncourt) asked, [over on Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/45768/did-stack-exchange-cut-the-number-of-negative-comments-nearly-in-half-between-th):

> Did Stack Exchange cut the number of negative comments nearly in half between the beginning of the fourth quarter of 2019 and January 21, 2020?

It's not really possible for someone outside the company to answer, and given that - it feels a little more appropriate to post a long answer here on Meta Stack Overflow<sup>*</sup> and then cite it over on Skeptics.

So I'm doing that.

<sub><sup>*</sup>The bits we have for this are only running on Stack Overflow, so I think this is technically a better place than Meta Stack Exchange.</sub>

Comment: It depends on how "negative" is defined. That's subjective. Next, it's unclear if that includes all posted comments or only the surviving comments of a certain age. And it surely also depends on the classification system. That might have a huge error. Probably nobody knows for sure. Okay, there is already an answer.

Comment: @Trilarion it's subjective to some extent but sentiment analysis is well studied in the field of natural language processing.

Comment: Just want to say, I *really* like how you went about this. Official response to the question, detail on meta, a short summary on Skeptics where it was asked; and of course, actually acknowledging the existence of the rest of the SE network, while explaining why it's all SO-focused! Very welcome and good to see.

Comment: I at first thought "negative" was commenting on the illegal relicensing or voicing support for fired moderators and CMs. And I at second thought it was true. i.e., I interpreted "negative" as "negative to / not in line with the company", not "unfriendly or unkind".

Comment: Unrelated discussion has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207358/discussion-on-question-by-kevin-montrose-did-stack-exchange-cut-the-number-of-ne).

Comment: It seems SE has managed to cut negative comments on questions like this: "I am a student and my professor said to explain this matlab code in scilab and i dont know nothing about it.So can anyone help me on this". We all have to agree that is great progress on making this site more welcoming while at the same time increasing question quality /s

Comment: @Alex SE didn't delete any comments, the automatic system presented here only proposes comments to the moderators for review, nothing more. If the moderators do delete valuable comments while cutting the negative comments, it would be on them, not on the proposal system. Indeed moderators might become too trustful of the automatic proposals, but I don't think this is actually happening. Maybe if there are new moderator elections in the future and more trigger happy moderators come into this position, it might become an issue.

Comment: Let me give you a quick answer, they did not cut down negative comments - they simply cut down on the number of users visiting the site...

Comment: That's right @JohH, I'd bet they have managed to cut down on ALL comments in that short period.  Probably questions too, and certainly answers

Comment: @JonH maybe not visitors as SO is still one of the best places to find existing qa. I would suggest instead they cut down on the number of veterans who don't ask/answer here anymore

Answer (score 197):

This is sort of two questions: "How are we measuring 'negative comments'?" and "Did the number of negative comments on SO decrease by ~50% in Q4 2019?"  My team (along with several others) worked on both sides, so I'll do my best to answer both.

### Measuring Negative Comments

First we have to be very specific about what we mean by "negative comments."  Stack Overflow is a bit unique in that the "negative" comments that survive are not the sorts of negative comments you find on a lot of the internet - we're not talking about hate speech, slurs, targeted harassment, and the like that many other online communities have to wrestle with.  We normally call these really egregious things "rude or abusive," like in the flag dialog.  The community and moderators of Stack Overflow do a really good job of keeping the "rude or abusive" content cleaned up, very little of it survives.

**The sort of negative comments we have to contend with are the "unkind, unwelcoming, or unfriendly" ones - those with condescending, dismissive, or otherwise subtly hostile phrasing.**  I feel like often there is confusion around this point since, in contrast to the "rude or abusive" cases, the intent of the commenter is rarely hostile.  In my experience this can make discussion of the issue more difficult, since it requires separating the comment and its impact on a reader from the commenter and their intent - which is very unnatural, especially emotionally.

A few years back we started work on quantifying the magnitude of our unwelcoming comment problem - we had heard, both anecdotally and in more structured user surveys, that it was an issue but it's hard to measure progress or make rational decisions in the absence of data.  To cut a long story short, we started with manually labeling new comments and progressed to using user generated flags and a human-in-the-loop automated flagging process.

The manual labeling started with employees, then rolled out to moderators, and then a wider group of volunteers.  That data suggested that somewhere between 5% & 10% of new comments were perceived, by at least one person, as unwelcoming in some way.  Later, we rolled out new flagging options for comments that allowed users to flag unwelcoming comments for moderator attention.

The data that was gathered from manual labeling and from the comment flags was used to train an auto flagger<sup>1</sup> (internally, we call it the Unfriendly Robot).  The robot doesn't delete anything, but it raises concerning comments for moderator attention - a setup often called "human in the loop".  We have iterated on the robot, mostly by taking the cases where moderators have disagreed as test cases, and the flags it raises are now at least as accurate as the flags raised by regular Stack Overflow users.  It is with this robot that we can now plot the change in negative comments over time.

**In summary**, we measure comment negativity using a custom algorithm that is trained on users' comment flags (and refined with moderators' responses to both those flags, and the algorithm's flags). Today when the algorithm raises flags, they are accepted at rates as high or higher than human raised flags.

### Reducing Negative Comments

One nuance right away, while Prashanth spoke about the absolute number of negative comments, internally we mostly talk about percentages.  In this case there isn't a practical difference, but he did make a (reasonable, IMO) simplification.

Given a way to classify negative comments, we can use it to look at the past and see how the prevalence of negative comments has evolved over time.  This lets us evaluate the impact of our efforts.

[image: Graph of unfriendly comment creation and 'still visible'-ness over time]

Cumulatively, the robot thinks they've taken Stack Overflow from something like 1.5% of new comments being unwelcoming to a little less than 1%.  This translates to something like a thousand improved comments a week, which get read by tens of thousands of people in the same period - and since content on Stack Overflow is consumed far more often than it is produced, the cumulative number of people impacted is even larger.

We've also used the robot to investigate *specific* changes, rather than just global trends.  For example, [Yaakov's work around post notices](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339700/new-post-notices-are-live-network-wide) flow appears to have [reduced the % of unfriendly comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/343285/51) on duplicate questions by ~10%.

### Caveats, Footnotes, Etc.

The big caveat to acknowledge is that it's not possible to split test most changes around welcoming-ness, and thus we can only infer causation - not prove it.  While, when we look at history, changes correlate to actions we'd expect to have had an impact - that is still only suggestive of causation, not proof of it.

Another thing to acknowledge is that, while I believe our efforts have made an impact on new content, there is still a very long tail (a decade or more of it) of old content. Changing perceptions of Stack Overflow's overall welcomingness to newcomers is a very large undertaking, and won't be accomplished by a single feature shipped or algorithm implemented.

Members of my team are planning at least one blog post that goes into the process of building the algorithm in detail, though it is a large enough and nuanced enough topic that it could still take a while to get published.  I also expect they'll want to explore some of the nuances between preventing unfriendly comments (with things like policy changes), addressing unfriendly comments (with things like flags), and handling the long tail of old content that still gets frequently viewed. There are already some older posts that have alluded to bits of this topic: [like](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/07/10/welcome-wagon-classifying-comments-on-stack-overflow/) [these](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/10/10/iterating-on-inclusion/) [three](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/06/21/rolling-out-the-welcome-wagon-june-update/).

A final thing I'd like to share - a lot of third-party approaches to these sorts of problems focus on users, building up profiles and histories to influence how they score particular pieces of text from those users.  **We explicitly decided against that approach.**  Our algorithms only consider the text of comments, no user specific details or user history are considered.  This decision follows naturally from the observation that these subtly unwelcoming comments are often not *intended* to be unwelcoming.

<sub><sup>1</sup>Because these are subtle and automated flags, they're a bit special.  Mostly, any of the systems that consider flag history or volume ignore these flags.</sub>

---

**Edit** (from Jason)

#### Was it Q4 2019?

To answer the title question: No, this particular thing definitely didn't happen in Q4 2019. Sorry for the confusion. In the original post Prashanth mentioned a bunch of things that did happen in Q4 and I think this was "thrown in for good measure". We haven't really talked about it much publicly for reasons and I think he was right to add it in, as it has happened.

#### Was it half?

For the 30 days leading up to "Stack Overflow is Unwelcoming" the average daily unfriendly comment percentage (by robot V2 reckoning) is 1.41% and the average count of daily unfriendly comments is 493.

For the 30 days leading up to today the average daily unfriendly comment percentage is 0.821% and the average count of daily unfriendly comments is 244.

On a percentage basis it's a stretch (we reduced the percentage 41.7% relative). On an absolute basis it's true (we reduced the number 50.5%).

#### "Did you try anything?"

"Did you try anything?" gets a .73 from UnfriendlyRobotV2. "Did you even try anything?" gets a .941. "Did you even bother to try anything?" gets a .978. The maximum is 1 and the threshold for an automated flag is .907. So no, "Did you try anything?" isn't getting anyone in trouble.

#### Can we say that there are more negative comments from post authors or from readers?

UnfriendlyRobotV2 marks 1,015,098 of 70,878,654 comments (1.43%) from Not-PostAuthors as unfriendly. It marks 323,182 of 32,148,152 comments (1.01%) from PostAuthors as unfriendly. The 95% confidence interval of a proportion test is 0.422% - 0.431% (this is the difference between the two percentages) with a p-value of 2.2e-16.

UnfriendlyRobotV2 thinks Not-PostAuthors are unfriendly 41%-42% more frequently than PostAuthors and the difference is statistically significant.

#### Can we say that there are more negative comments under questions or under answers?

(Jason: I'm getting tired of saying UnfriendlyRobotV2, so I'm just gonna call it the robot from here on out).

The robot marks 508,183 of 50,763,777 comments (1%) on Answers as unfriendly. The robot marks 931,338 of 55,658,832 comments (1.67%) on Questions as unfriendly. The 95% confidence interval of a proportion test is .668% - .677% with a p-value of 2.2e-16.

The robot thinks that comments on Questions are 66%-67% more frequently unfriendly than comments on Answers and the difference is statistically significant.

#### Did 3CV change anything?

We moved the close vote threshold around in the second half of 2019. Did that have any effect on the percentage of unfriendly comments?

[image: Unfriendly Comments and the 3 Close Vote change]

This was not an A/B test, so there's no control to compare against. All we can really do is look at a trend line. I don't see much of a change during the original 30-day experiment period. There's some rolloff in 2020, but I'd be hard pressed to attribute any of it to the final change which was made on December 3.

#### How helpful is the robot?

What percentage of robot flags are helpful? Here's a plot that puts it alongside the same metric for humans. (Human flags here are both Rude/Abusive and Unfriendly/Unkind as that's what the robot is trained on)

[image: Flags Percent Helpful by Source]

Robot V1 was definitely not up to the task (there were tons of false positives). Robot V2 *looks* as if it's doing well but it's jumped around a bit and recently has fallen to "merely" human levels. It's natural to come up with another metric which we call "The Robot Rating" and calculate as Robot %Helpful / Human %Helpful. That plot looks like this...

[image: Robot Rating]

That isn't the whole story though, because the robot never sleeps. There is no comment that escapes its roboty eye. Let's plot helpful flags by source...

[image: Helpful Flags by Source]

We see that even though V1 wasn't so accurate it still raised tons more helpful flags than humans did. (V1, though diligent, did get sick at the end of its tenure and dropped off a bit to "merely" human). How much are we improving detection using the robot? We get a multiplier by taking the ratio of Robot Helpful Flags to Human Helpful flags...

[image: Detection Improvement]

V1 helped us find 2X-3X more unfriendly comments than humans flagging alone. V2 has routinely been above 3X.

The robot gives a score to each comment. How helpful is the robot conditioned on score? If we round robot scores to the nearest percent and calculate percent helpful at each rounded score we get this...

[image: Percent Helpful by Robot Score]

We can see that in both versions the higher the score the more likely our moderators agree with the robot. We also see a jump in helpfulness across all scores that came with robot V2.

Comment: Gonna put a small comment here to say that I collected a lot of this quickly from other folks who did the real work, so don't be shocked if there are some edits (from myself or other employees) to fix any mistakes I might have made in the collation.

Comment: Could you quantify how much useful information was lost in the process? [It's](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/370792/1394393) [clear](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7753287#7753287) that many comments SO has deemed "unwelcoming" were quite helpful.

Comment: Am I missing something? Based on this chart it looks like in Q4 2019 you had a little under 1% (maybe .85 or .9) and at the end of the chart (presumably Jan 21 2020) it was down to maybe .8 or .75. How is that a cut in half? I feel like I'm misreading something. Is the red line the total number of unfriendly comments, visible and not? And where are you getting 1.5% and 1% from?

Comment: @David "Cumulatively the robot thinks they've...", the they've there is "our efforts" which started at "Stack Overflow is Unwelcoming". We didn't reduce them by half in Q4 2019. Could be more clear. I'll get an edit in in the morning.

Comment: I'll also say "Half" is probably stretching it. (Though the first version of the Unfriendly Robot did say that. That version did have a lot of false positives that appeared to be resolved when we released version 2)

Comment: @JasonPunyon Thanks. Can't say I fully get you yet, so I'm looking forward to the edit. I'm also going off the skeptics post which says `...that plot that suggests a 50% reduction in negative comments` and that isn't making sense in my head

Comment: I'm interested in false negative rates. You say that volunteers have rated 5-10% of all new comments as unwelcoming in some way. If we take that statistic as relatively accurate, then your bot only catches around 1/10 to 1/2.5 of the unwelcoming comments. Are there any data points to show that your approach successfully extrapolates to that number, e.g that the unwelcoming comments were reduced by actually 50%?

Comment: **[Example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370792/is-this-really-what-we-should-consider-unwelcoming) of negative comment**: _Also, any time you have enumerated columns, you can be sure that something’s gone very, very wrong with your design. That said, you’re probably after LEAST(). But don’t do that. Fix your design."_

Comment: You should edit your post and include some of the comments jpmc26 linked.

Comment: @Fermiparadox the comment you quoted may not be strictly 'unfriendly', however it is certainly unhelpful/unneccessary. It is something that I have encountered as an asker as well: Instead of someone answering the question you get a bunch of "you shouldn't do it that way" "you are doing it wrong" ... . The asker may even know that it is wrong but either there is no better/quicker way of solving it OR it is old code and the person asking is just trying to fix it. Just writing a short "Hey can you do it this way? Then you won't have that issue." says the same and is friendlier/more helpful.

Comment: @SteffenWinkler, yeah, as much as I like to pile on SEs mistakes lately, I agree for that example. The comment is *not* **hostile**, but it's kind of annoying.

Comment: @SteffenWinkler I've had the exact opposite experience. I was doing something the wrong way and i got a similar comment. It was _very helpful_ in my case.

Comment: _"perceived, by at least one person, as unwelcoming"_ - one out of how many?

Comment: @SteffenWinkler Problem is, this is how developers talk... if I have to say something is wrong I will just say it, yes, people might have reason to do things the "wrong" way... but more often than not, they just don't know better. Also such comments and answers are not only for the OP but for other devs that might come across some piece of code and think this is a good way to do something. WE MUST POINT MISTAKES IN APPROACH, that is the only way people (we all) can learn and improve.

Comment: @Fermiparadox which is why I wrote the last sentence in my comment: It can be helpful, but - to be a bit hyperbolic - it shouldn't be demanded to change your code because it doesn't conform to the latest hyped up idea of how code should look like.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar " this is how developers talk". Last time I checked I was a software developer. I don't talk like that. Some developers sometimes are 'set in their ways' like that, yes. But it isn't the norm judging from my experience. Are developers usually more direct than others? Yes. But being direct doesn't mean being annoying to the point of being unhelpful.

Comment: To reinforce Steffen's point, IME it's often the person providing the "helpful" comment (or answer) who needs to go through a painful growth experience. There are some commenters (and answer people) who are both a little harsh and actually not completely correct - missing context, nuance, etc.

Comment: @Fermiparadox, I finally understood what all this reminds me. I mean: "Community has to be renewed" "negative comments .. are ... those with condescending, dismissive, or otherwise subtly hostile phrasing". How many of you remember fidonet and usenet groups? How many of you have seen and 100% agree with the classic [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)? The Introduction section says at all. SO users with the attitude of hackers (as described in the link) has to be renewed.

Comment: Sometimes it depends how people read the comment, rather than the person who wrote it. eg. "you need to fix your design" can be interpreted as "you are a moron and your design is junk and you need to fix the way you think", or "a bug in your design is the real problem here that should be addressed first or you'll run into more errors later" - this is why you should assume good intent with everything you read on t'interwebs, there is no nuance or context to help you.

Comment: @SteffenWinkler Most of devs I know talk like that... I talk like that... yes, I know some that talk differently... point is if someone is bent on perceiving direct comments like that as offensive... then I really have nothing to say to them. I cannot change who I am... I can be nicer but that requires extensive effort on my side... I am not going to bother doing that... most people I know will not bother either. I am here to help people.. I usually have few minutes while something is compiling... if I have to get out of my head to write comment, I will just skip commenting and just CV and DV.

Comment: @SteffenWinkler "The asker may even know that it is wrong but either there is no better/quicker way of solving it OR it is old code and the person asking is just trying to fix it." **Then they need to include that information in their question from the start.** Claiming people who are trying to help are wrong, just because the person asking the question didn't go to effort of being specific, is offensive on every level.

Comment: @IanKemp Stating specific requirements is a must. But even when you have some specific requirement and you think you cannot use solution X, someone might come along with better solution Y that can be applied more easily. Been there million times on both ends.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Indeed, but in that case it isn't appropriate to be condescending. This is the fundamental problem with the stats and claims about "unwelcoming": it entirely lacks context. Consider: a user asks a s**t question that demonstrates they didn't bother to read any part of the Help Center, and gets unwelcoming comments; versus a user asks a good question, and gets unwelcoming comments. To my mind the comments on the second case are far worse, and thus those comments should be weighted more heavily as unwelcoming; yet there is no evidence that Stack Exchange is doing this.

Comment: @IanKemp both parts aren't ideal. A good system gives new users enough guidance that they never come in "without any idea" of what they're doing. Two wrongs don't make a right, however, so snarking is never actually useful. It's more _excusable_ from a personal PoV, but not helpful either way.

Comment: @Magisch I understand and accept that, but I'm also a human being. I try to be kind and understanding and approachable, but it becomes difficult when I'm overloaded and/or my attempts to help aren't appreciated. And that's exactly what's happening with the horde of self-entitled new users being encouraged to use SO as a free helpdesk/tech support/code writing service. The unwelcoming problem is a symptom of the new users problem, and as long as SE Inc continues to ignore the latter, they won't be able to solve the former. That won't stop them from blaming everyone else for the former, natch.

Comment: I have seen some real jerk responses... but they are plain offensive there is nothing subtle about those. I am not defending such comments. But plain direct comments that just might be perceived as unfriendly... well, call me unfriendly then ;)

Comment: @Magisch "snarking is never actually useful" - mostly agree, but that's not relevant here. Based on the example comments shown by SE, they define comments as "unwelcoming" not only if they are snarky, but also if they are simply not sugarcoated or fluffed up enough.

Comment: I just wonder if the frequently observed "Did you try anything?" comment would be included in unfriendly comments?

Comment: "Prashanth spoke about the absolute number of negative comments internally"  So the absolute number of negative comments has been reduced simply because the number of active users has dropped? Our customers are leaving and this is good news! That's plain bizarre.

Comment: @Lundin, there should be a comma between the words "comments" and internally". Then the sentence reads properly.

Comment: @Lundin The absolute number of comments hasn't changed much during the last months, so in this case it's the same as the rate of negative comments, but the rate is what you would usually look at.

Comment: I consider this data extremely implausible. A massive amount of negativity has been directed at the site management over the last few months, probably orders of magnitude more than there has ever been on the site in its entire history. (And I've been here for most of it.) A massive number of comments have been silently deleted, again, probably vastly more than at any time in the site's history. Exactly what criteria were used to exclude those comments from this data?

Comment: @VladimirBaranov "Hackers", as described in that link, provide 100% of this site's real value.

Comment: Does "This is stupid. Dates should be stored as dates, not as strings" count as negative comment?

Comment: @SalmanA "This is stupid. Dates should be stored as dates, not as strings" gets a .948 from UnfriendlyRobotV2. The threshold for an automated flag is .907, so yes, that would "count" and be flagged for a moderator to look at.

Comment: @Fermiparadox The comment you reference as an example gets a .667 from UnfriendlyRobotV2. That would not meet the threshold (.907) for moderator attention.

Comment: I'm in an ongoing conversation with an asker. At one point I noticed that my most recent comment in the conversation had been deleted without giving me any notice, so I thought it was some fluke and I posted another comment so that the asker would know I was waiting for more information. The comment was deleted *again* without notifying me. If I hadn't been checking up on the conversation then neither I nor the asker would have known that any action was needed, with each of us thinking the ball was in the other's court. Would it be possible to set up notifications for comment deletions?

Comment: @user560822, I agree. And still, hackers are not welcome on SO anymore. "The first thing to understand is that hackers actually like hard problems and good, thought-provoking questions about them. If we didn't, we wouldn't be here. Despite this, hackers have a reputation for meeting simple questions with what looks like hostility or arrogance. It sometimes looks like we're reflexively rude to newbies and the ignorant. But this isn't really true. What we are, unapologetically, is hostile to people who seem to be unwilling to think or to do their own homework before asking questions."

Comment: @SteffenWinkler Are you kidding? Telling someone point blank that they're having an XY-problem and to fix the real problem is unhelpful? What about the poor sap who has to maintain the code that's so poorly designed? You *never* just answer the question when the asker is looking to do something ill advised. You *tell* them it's ill advised. And if they really know what they're doing, they'll come back and say, "Right, normally this is a bad idea, but because of reasons a, b, and c, this situation is exceptional." And then those specifics should be edited into the question.

Comment: @KyleDelaney "Would it be possible to set up notifications for comment deletions?" For sure it's possible, but I doubt you'll knock on open doors there.

Comment: @SalmanA You could try "This is not a very wise way. Dates should be stored as dates, not as strings." .

Comment: @jpmc26 are you kidding? Please read my entire comment before going off like that. Because that was my exact point, while the quoted comment literally said that if the asker doesn't change their code they will not receive any further help.

Comment: @Alex Your comment doesn't make any sense. What you are talking about has literally nothing to do with what kinds of comments are allowed and wether or not people get to use swear words. You may want to read [the help-center article about valid questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Last time I checked you didn't need to write a single comment to flag a question.

Comment: Not directly related to the stated question, but I observe from the graph that around mid 2018, the amount of unfriendly comments was fairly rapidly declining on its own accord until the point where the CoC was introduced, after which it almost levelled. This strongly suggests that the CoC was *counterproductive* and detrimental to the perceived friendliness of the site.

Comment: @EmilJeřábeksupportsMonica The data shown here suggests at least that SO is becoming more and more welcome everyday and never was more welcome than today, by itself and with the help of the moderation.

Comment: So only about 1% to 1.5% of the comments is 'Did you even try anything' or worse? How come people think SO is unwelcoming then?

Comment: @JasonPunyon with regards to what to compare to 3CV, it would be natural to gauge it against numbers of negative comments cast during the old threshold times, wouldn't it. In some sense there is your A/B, in comparing amounts of comments discovered by robot within different timeframes

Comment: @gnat You could do that, but there was all kinds of different things happening in those periods that could also cause whatever effect you detected. For instance in the middle (where we were back at 5) we were doing post notices.

Comment: I see. Indeed my initial suggestion that this would be a proper analog for a real A/B test now looks like a stretch, forget it. Thanks for explaining @JasonPunyon

Comment: I've seen a lot of this before, and some has been shared with moderators privately as well... But I want to express my gratitude to @Jason and Kevin for making it public and taking the time to answer questions here. The shape of the problem has been known for nearly 7 years now, but tracking it with this level of detail and broadly communicating its nature has made scaling tooling to address it almost impossible - I am confident that the work y'all have put into this will prove invaluable.

Comment: @user560822 The unfriendly robot only looks at comments posted on Stack Overflow. Anything that's happening on metas or other Q&A sites doesn't factor into it.

Comment: @GolezTrol Probably because a couple people said so on Twitter

Comment: @SteffenWinkler How is a guide on valid questions going to help me post comments ?

Comment: @GolezTrol You cannot have a system the size of Stack Overflow's at one nine of uptime and expect no one to notice.

Comment: @JasonPunyon "I'm getting tired of saying UnfriendlyRobotV2, so I'm just gonna call it the robot from here on out" you just lost the opportunity of calling it UR-V2.

Comment: @GolezTrol also, usually extreme cases are the ones that are heard most about, just because it evokes the most intense feelings (humans are emotional creatures, not rational ones, and tend to remember negative experiences more than positive ones) which we then act upon. To that you have to add all the formal and informal bias.

Comment: @JasonPunyon or Kevin, can we build the opposite of UR-V2? A bot to mark helpful comments and give them priority to be shown to users?

Comment: Why do the robots seem to be initially helpful, then gradually lose effectiveness?

Comment: I wonder, if the UC-R2 detected 4x times as much negative comments, why is the dent in the blue curve shown at the beginning of the answer only so low? Humans alone seem to have cut the negative comments rate by 1%, now it's at 0.5%. But then you say it's 4 times more powerful. How does that fit together?

Comment: @CJDennis Maybe the robot kind of defeats its own purpose. Maybe in the beginning they presented the low hanging fruit (highest score) first and now come the cases that are more ambiguous. Or maybe the moderators, which are the gold standard here, become more distrustful of the results of the robot over time.

Comment: How do you bounty on meta??

Comment: I have never seen a website work harder to make a place welcoming... actually quantifying the unfriendliness of comments. It's beautiful. I do find it a little ironic that some people get their feelings hurt when you suggest that they're wrong to rudely tell someone that they're wrong.

Comment: Wow.  After that scintillating essay I'm definitely considering not participating in comments/answers from this point on.  Who is SE/SO to sculpt the minds of the people that OFFER THEIR HELP FOR FREE?  Well, they own the site so I guess they have the right to do what they want with their toys.  This bit of wording is ok, but this bit over here is not.  Think right or you shan't be heard from.  I don't think I want SE/SO playing their psychology games with me.

Comment: I tried to help pointing, very polite, in a comment  to a Xilinx app note (Xilinx has thousand of the things) . But it was removed. I have to assume if was seen as "RTFM".  If they counted mine to the pile of 'negative comments removed' then yes, I can imagine their score is high. At least they made sure that that I don't bother anymore.

Comment: @SteffenWinkler *"the comment you quoted may not be strictly 'unfriendly', however it is certainly unhelpful/unneccessary"* - this is weasel words. Almost nothing is necessary.

Answer (score 19):

As an answer focusing exclusively on Skeptics.SE question [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/393654/839601) is maybe OK but for meta post it seems to be bit lean on substance.

I think providing some additional statistics and correlation analysis could help us understand what could be done to further decrease negative comments. Below is what I would like to see in a meta report on this matter (hardly relevant to Skeptics question, sorry).

---

Can we say that there are more negative comments from post authors or from readers (or more precisely, whether available statistics lets us tell this with reasonable confidence).

Can we say that there are more negative comments under questions or under answers.

Do we observe a correlation between negative comments and posts score (or amount of votes up/down, and additionally, votes close / reopen for questions).

Speaking of score, it would be useful to learn whether [recent experiment of hiding negative score](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/390414/839601) made any observable impact on negative comments.

The last but not the least, whether there was a confidently observable impact of [introducing 3CV threshold](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/391832/839601), including its [trial run](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388313/839601) few months before.

Comment: I answered your first two in edits to Kevin's answer. The rest are really tricky to get to the bottom of. Some of the difficulty has to do with changing data (post scores change all the time), some of it is the design of those experiments.

Comment: thanks @Jason - data you added makes great food for thought! Wrt correlation with score / votes, I was thinking simply of most recent values of those - assuming that for most posts these somehow stabilize over time, does that make sense?

Comment: @JasonPunyon  I am confused about what could be difficult about correlating with 3CV threshold. I thought it is a simple matter of getting average amount of negative comments having date within timeframe of a new threshold, do I miss something? As for A/B test of hiding negative score, I gave it more thought and you seem to be right about it - it looks hard (maybe even impossible) to figure a way to get data to make a reliable conclusion, everything I considered so far leaves a room for mistakes in the interpretation

Comment: Ah, for some reason I thought 3CV was an A/B test. We just turned it on for 30 days originally. This is easier to pull than I thought, but we will just be eyeballing a graph (there's no control for any statistical tests).

Comment: Added a graph on 3CV.

Comment: thank you @JasonPunyon - visually it looks like there was no impact worth talking about

Answer (score 6):

I would imagine the system feedback *while users type out their question* (e.g. "Your question seems to be mostly code...") has played at least some small part in reducing potential negative comments.

**Can the robot be trained on questions as well?**  I.e. what kind of questions tend to produce negative comments?

Then, is it possible to integrate that into the question-asking process?  As long as the feedback seems to be system-generated, improved questions -> fewer negative comments -> better overall perception.

And, you can certainly A/B test this process.

Comment: You imagine things that we also imagine. One thing the robot finds is that "homework" is a token associated with unfriendliness. Using "questions with comments with the token 'homework'" as a positive set and "random questions" as a negative set I've trained a model (using the exact same software) that detects questions with eerily homework like qualities. Hooking that second model into the question asking flow so we can eagerly inform and educate question askers about our homework policies seems like a straightforward way to tackle a certain subset of unfriendliness.

Comment: I also did a prototype of an "images of code" detector that could be used the same way... https://twitter.com/JasonPunyon/status/1180094373234651138

Answer (score 5):

The auto flagging of comments by a trained system and feeding to moderators for review in the second half of 2019 seems to have had a big impact. I'm convinced that the fraction of negative comments has gone down because of it, but the question here is by how much? Regardless of the how much, I think it is an important step forward and I like it very much.

There are some more caveats than mentioned in the answer by Kevin Montrose, mainly the false negative rate already mentioned by Magisch in a comment, so I want to discuss a bit, what errors could still be in that estimated cutting-the-number-nearly-in-half-statement. Of course, it's difficult to include all details in a blog post, but writing "we cut the number of those negative comments that we are aware of nearly in half" instead would probably have been better.

**Everyone has a different threshold for negative comments. The calculated rate of removed negative comments might depend on it.**

For example, is "Did you try anything?" a negative comment? It surely is a frequent comment. Some might say yes, others might say no. Overall, people could have different thresholds, resulting in different perceived actual fractions of negative comments. Is it 1% negative comments, or rather 2% or 5% or 10%, it may be up to your personal opinion and that may influence the results here. For example, Julia Silge reported a factor of two difference in the fraction of unwelcome comments present depending on the group you ask [in 2018](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/12/04/welcome-wagon-community-and-comments-on-stack-overflow/).

We know probably exactly how many comments we deleted and they could be seen by definition as negative comments. The difficulty is rather in estimating how many negative comments there are in order to estimate by which factor they have been cut.

**The false positive error rate or why was the number of negative comments only cut in half?**

In the official answer here, it is reported that the accuracy, i.e. the fraction of flagged comments that got deleted later-on, is as high as for the manual flags. But what is it really? Probably at least 50% because the blue curve seems to have dropped by 50% in 2019, but how low is the false positive rate?

This false positive rate should be taken into account, if it was 50% (and there were no false negatives) then actually negative comments would have been completely wiped out as of 2019. The statement in the CEO's blog post would have been too modest.

**The false negative error rate or which negative comments did the robot miss?**

This is by far the greater unknown here, I guess. If the auto flagging did not include all negative comments, then one could expect that those kind of negative comments that are more difficult to detect automatically are not cut in half too, because they would not have profited from the increased moderator attention. That could mean that the number of negative comments could have been cut in less than half. The statement in the CEO's blog post would have been too optimistic. One way out would have been to explicitly restrict the statement to those negatives that they are aware of.

**The presence of the effect is not a surprise.**

The number of negative comments is estimated by the algorithm that is responsible for feeding these comments to the moderators. They will surely delete some of them. There had to be an impact. But maybe the auto flagging tool has a too high threshold (to avoid too many false positives) and may miss out on some negative comments.

**The lifetime of negative comments.**

In the answer by Kevin Montrose, it is hinted that the real impact is how many people actually see negative comments. The lifetime of a negative comment before it gets deleted is therefore equally important as the mere fact that it gets deleted eventually. The fraction of negative comments that exist on Stack Overflow at any given moment in time is probably somewhere between the blue and the red curve presented. That would be the interesting curve and it would depend on lifetime and deletion rate both.

**Summary**

All in all there is a bit of room for error, and especially if the false negative rate is high, the statement might be a bit too optimistic. If it wasn't then Stack Overflow made a great leap towards eliminating unwelcomingness.

Comment: "Did you try anything?" gets a .73 from UnfriendlyRobotV2. "Did you even try anything?" gets a .941. "Did you even bother to try anything?" gets a .978. The maximum is 1 and the threshold for an automated flag is .907.

Comment: @JasonPunyon Thanks for the values. So we could just replace version 2 and 3 with version 1 everywhere and call it mission accomplished, maybe. ;)

Comment: @JasonPunyon "Did you try anything?" is arguably as neutral a comment as it gets, so it should have a rating around .5 (50%). That it sits at almost 75% basically shows how skewed and biased the detection is.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers The goal of the project isn't to have a specific score of a specific comment be palatable to a specific user. The goal is to bring comments that need attention to the attention of our moderators. We (correctly) would not raise this comment.

Comment: @Trilarion lol 

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers The score doesn't have to be scaled so that 0.5 is meaningful. It's just a number below or above the threshold and that is all that is important. I wonder how well more veiled attacks are detected, it seems to be more like a "watch your language son" thing you might hear in your parents home. I wish though they would employ it on other popular Internet places. I can hardly believe Google or Facebook or Twitter cannot do the same.

Comment: If you say so. I for one am *way* past assuming good intentions.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Yes, there are critical aspects of their automatic detection but they are more to do with the threshold less with the absolute values of the score. Why is the threshold 0.907, why not 0.99 or 0.8?

Comment: @Trilarion I bet that threshold is roughly "moderators can comfortably handle X comment flags a day - set threshold to automatically flag ~X*0.5 comments a day". Probably with some adjusting depending on current needs - down if more training for robot would be needed (to get more comments reviewed by mods) or up to free up mods time if large number of auto-flagged comments not get deleted. 0.9 is likely just that round enough number that currently satisfy all needs.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov If this would be true it would be an indication that there is no control of the false negative rate and the true rate of cutting down negative comments as reported by the CEO could be anything. In the answer to the skeptics question it ends with "it's my professional opinion that the number really is cut in half" or something similar. Who would give a professional judgment without having at least an idea of the number of items you might miss out in the calculation.

Comment: Hey so I added some more graphs to Kevin's answer. The false negative question is a good one. I can't answer it without an oracle, but we can see how many false negatives there are for humans, given that the robot is running.