# Have the comments posted on Stack Overflow by itself become more friendly over the years?

Tags: discussion, comments, statistics, welcoming

Looking at the graph showing the historic evolution of the percentage of unfriendly comments made (red line) as detected by the Unfriendly Comments Robot v2 (UC-R2) taken from [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/393654/1536976) of [Did Stack Exchange cut the number of negative comments nearly in half between the beginning of the fourth quarter of 2019 and January 21, 2020?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/393653/did-stack-exchange-cut-the-number-of-negative-comments-nearly-in-half-between-th), it looks a bit as if, except for a bump in 2018, the fraction of unfriendly comments made has gone down quite steadily.

[image: Graph of unfriendly comment creation and 'still visible'-ness over time]

I take it that the red curve describes the situation before any moderation or comment flagging took place and depicts the fraction of new comments at each time detected by UC-R2 for a given threshold. The long term trend since the beginning seems to be pretty positive in terms of friendliness and comments made on Stack Overflow supposedly never were more friendly than now.

Is this reading correct? What is likely the cause for it? Did people in general become more friendly over the last decade maybe or is the long-standing effort of the moderation and flagging (and as of late also automatic detection) of comments paying off over the years, kind of establishing a culture of friendliness on SO over the years? Or maybe something else?

A bias by the classification method is unlikely because it was only invented in 2018-2019, so commenters in the past didn't know that their comments would be classified now. Also over the years millions of new users joined and commented and also millions stopped participating as well. There is a huge turn over although some people surely took part for a longer time and may have changed their behavior. Finally, there were UI changes at some time points that have an influence, but the long term trend is so broad and long-lasting, I would not really assign the full effect just to them.

Finally: If this graph somehow says that Stack Overflow never was more welcoming at least comment-wise, why do [site satisfaction surveys](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/01/22/the-loop-2-understanding-site-satisfaction-summer-2019/) put welcomingness problems at the top of most often named problems? Could it mean that there aren't really any pressing problems currently or are the reported welcomingness problems unrelated to comments or are the detection results of UC-R2 maybe not representative? Or maybe something else?

Comment: Hell yes we're friendly AF these days. — Anecdotally speaking I think fatigue is part of the answer. There are simply too many posts to be snarky about these days to even bother. Downvote-and-move-on seems more efficient. ;)

Comment: I've only used SO for a few years but seeing changes like when flagging a question as a duplicate now automatically adding comments like "did this answer your question" does indeed come across more "friendly" however, I don't believe SO actually had a massive issue with friendliness.

Comment: it feels as if we're at the fourth round of the [story told here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366750/839601) "it once happened that someone up the management ladder came up with a concern..."

Comment: I don't think comments were ever at the core of the welcoming bandwagon. People post without familiarizing themselves with the site, then complain about the fallout when regulars point out their errors. There are several systemic errors which could be fixed by updating the software, but these days the popular tactic seems to be to blame the regulars.

Comment: @tripleee So you say that when people complain about unwelcomingness they mean critical, but friendly comments or other actions like downvotes? Little is known about what people really complained about in the site surveys, but it seems like at least some complained that "Some people are often condescending or rude". I take it that this is rather meant about comments.

Comment: I'm sure there *was* a problem with unfriendly comments, and I'm pretty sure the answer to your question as such is that there is less of a problem with them now; only I'm thinking the downvotes etc are a substantial part of the larger problem of people feeling unwelcome as well. But there's a bit too much speculation here along the way, starting from what the survey really meant and whether the remedies have actually helped. I'll go out on a limb and speculate further that being more welcoming at the doorstep leads to more people realizing in the foyer that this is not where they wanted to be

Comment: @tripleee I looked at the ratio of down- to upvotes recently and it was falling in the last couple of years. Even in that regard we might have become more "friendly". Maybe it's more like they realize in the foyer that nobody is there.

Comment: While there was a drastic dip recently of unfriendly comments visible on the site, it's been trending upwards since then. I suspect this "negative comments cut in half" will be effectively undone within a year.

Comment: @KevinB Do you mean the sudden fall in the blue line in 2019 that kind of bounces back since then? The red line is going down steadily, except for a temporary bump in 2018.