# Downvotes Survey results

Tags: discussion, product-discovery, downvotes

Last fall, we conducted a [survey on why users downvote](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402061/downvotes-survey-launching-oct-15-2020) on Stack Overflow. It ran for four weeks and produced 1,455 responses. Here is what we learned.

- Improving content quality and reducing noise are the two main motivators for users who downvote.
- Most users downvote because the author didn’t demonstrate enough research or because the post was unclear/unhelpful.
- On questions, users tend to downvote to inform the author. On answers, they downvote to inform other users.
- More experienced users are more likely to leave a comment/upvote a comment or vote to close a post along with their downvote.

### **Who took the survey**

We randomly sampled 10% of users who clicked the downvote icon on a question or answer. When they clicked to downvote, they saw a call-to-action to take the survey. More downvotes came from answers (57.2%) than questions (42.8%).

Downvoting is a [privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) reserved for registered users of Stack Overflow who have a reputation of at least 125. Almost 90% of the respondents were registered users, and 56.5% actually had the downvote privilege. (Anonymous and lower-reputation users can click the downvote icon, but their votes don't affect the score.)

| Reputation | Percent of respondents |
| --- | --- |
| 0-9 | 10.9% |
| 10-49 | 13.7% |
| 50-124 | 12.2% |
| 125-1999 | 29.8% |
| 2000+ | 33.3% |

### Survey results

#### **Why did you choose to downvote this last post? Select all that apply.**

| Option | Percent |
| --- | --- |
| The post did not demonstrate that sufficient research or sufficient effort was put in by the post-author | 46.94% |
| The question or answer was unclear or unuseful | 42.54% |
| Other | 30.17% |
| The post-author should make an edit | 14.78% |
| The post was obviously spam (unsolicited advertisement) | 3.44% |

Half of the registered respondents chose “The post did not demonstrate that sufficient research or sufficient effort was put in by the post-author,” compared to ~35% of anonymous users. This makes sense since registered users are more likely to be familiar with the norms of Stack Overflow and the level of detail required for a question to be useful.

There were differences in downvoting behavior between questions and answers.

For questions:

- Users wanted to improve question quality and reduce noise.
- Off-topic questions, homework/free-coding requests and questions with a lack of detail were the most likely to receive downvotes.
- ~70% of the respondents chose to downvote questions because the post did not demonstrate enough research or effort by the author.
- A higher percentage of respondents also said that authors should edit questions vs. answers.

For answers:

- Users wanted to reduce noise — especially when there were other qualified answers —  to help other users who were seeking the correct answer.
- Answers that contained incorrect information, low quality info or off-topic material were the most likely to receive downvotes.

#### **In addition to your downvote, what other actions did you or will you take on this post? Select all that apply.**

| Option | Percent |
| --- | --- |
| I only downvoted | 54.66% |
| I left a comment | 22.49% |
| I upvoted an existing comment | 13.91% |
| I voted to close | 12.57% |
| Other | 7.47% |
| I flagged the post | 5.62% |
| I made/suggested an edit | 5.55% |
| I voted to delete | 5.55% |
| I followed the post | 2.74% |

70% of anonymous users noted that they “only downvoted.” This makes sense, as anonymous users do not have any of the listed privileges.

For registered users, almost 25% of respondents said that they left or would leave a comment, which is consistent with normal observed behavior on the site. The response with the next highest rate for registered users was “I upvoted an existing comment.” This suggests that in the context of downvoting, comments are primarily used as a way to provide feedback for the original poster.

When splitting by rep level, 27.5% of 2000+ rep users said that they would vote to close the question. Closing questions is a privilege that is earned at 3000 rep, so most respondents didn't have this ability.

#### **Who do you think your downvote helps to inform?**

| Option | Percent |
| --- | --- |
| Both the post-author and other users | 55.61% |
| Other users | 25.83% |
| The post-author | 15.76% |
| Neither the post-author nor other users | 2.80% |

Registered users (>50%) were more likely to select that the downvote is for both the post-author and other users, whereas anonymous users were more likely to say that the downvote was only to help inform other users.

For downvotes on questions, respondents were more likely to note that the downvote was to help inform the post-author. For answers, the respondents were more likely to say that the downvote was for other users. This implies that for questions, the downvote was to give feedback to the original poster that there was an issue with the question, whereas for answers, it is to warn other users that there is an issue with the answer and it needs more scrutiny.

### **Next steps: how we'll use this data**

We are in early discovery on a project to improve new user onboarding (stay tuned for a Meta post). We've identified a subset of users that we call "strugglers." These users actively participate on Stack Overflow, but experience negative outcomes from their actions, such as being downvoted often and frequently having their questions closed.

Our goal is to help these new users better understand the rules and norms of Stack Overflow so that they can participate successfully on the platform. The insights gained from this downvotes survey will help influence our approach to user onboarding.

Comment: I don't see anything new from these results. We already knew as much. Both downvotes and upvotes have a description when you hover over them. It is a way to rank the content. I wonder how this helps you in making further improvements.

Comment: *"Most users downvote because the author didn’t demonstrate enough research or because the post was unclear/unhelpful."* That *is* what the tooltip says the downvote reason is for. I find that there are very few that vote for other reasons; and then it's normally for the user not the content and I *doubt* someone would admit that they did that (even in a survey).

Comment: Thank you for releasing and bringing hard data about downvotes to future discussions, whether about onboarding or beyond. I suspect (fear?) that the reaction on Meta will likely be one of "told you so," but there is still incredible value here, because we now have real numbers to reference; downvote data is now no longer purely anecdotal. I like these research initiatives a lot.

Comment: Clever way of hiding how few results came from users over 2k, a rather common trend in most recent SO surveys

Comment: @kevin b If I'm not mistaken, >2k+ is even overrepresented in the survey, compared to the user stats https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/year/stackoverflow/2021-01-01

Comment: For overall users, yes, but for users who use the downvote privilege?

Comment: How do you know which users use the downvote privilege?

Comment: @Dharman This is water is wet. And as always: it's good to have data to confirm our believes.

Comment: Does downvoting more often increase the probability of being in the survey? Or did 10% of users get the popup?

Comment: It is slightly disappointing (the data, not the research itself) that the results are as expected, but it is really nice to have a breakdown of the usual reasons for downvoting - this is *tangible* and a basis for something more constructive than anecdotal evidence. It would be great if we could also have a breakdown of the "Other" option (at least a high-level overview or a selection of more peculiar reasons). 30% means quite a few people had something else to say about why they voted this way.

Comment: I'm trying to digest how about 40% of responses are from people who don't even have capability to down vote due to rep < 125. Or am I missing something?

Comment: oh, and another thing - it would also be nice to break 2K+ category into 2K, 5K, and 10K (maybe even 20K) as my gut feeling tells me the numbers should go higher the more rep the responder has, but cannot confirm that from the current breakdown.

Comment: @charlietfl these are taken for anonymous feedback. We are trying to capture the intention behind the click, not whenever the user is capable.

Comment: @KevinB We sampled downvote clicks at 10% and excluded users who received an invitation to take the Site Satisfaction Survey within the last 90 days, those who previously dismissed the Downvote Survey invitation, and those who previously clicked through to the survey. It was per vote, not first vote.

Comment: @OlegValter We didn't break 2K+ category down further. To protect anonymity, we passed rep as the bands in the first table vs. raw rep numbers.

Comment: @AnitaTaylor - eh, too bad, it would be a valuable data point, but it is understandable. Btw, as mentioned above, is there a way to get an analysis of custom voting reasons (or as a raw data dump)? I am sure there are some very useful insights in the real reasons why people downvote posts.

Comment: @charlietfl I'm not surprised that *some* people without sufficient rep click the up or down vote buttons (I sometimes do it accidentally myself on HNQ questions on sites that I'm not a member of). But I *am* surprised that the number is so high: I expected it to be more like 2 or 3%, max. I guess that indicates that there are a *lot* of people casually using SO who don't have a clue how it works. FWIW, I was reading SO answers for a couple of years before I decided to join, and I didn't bother reading any of the Help info before I joined (but I did read the Tour before making my first post).

Comment: @PM2Ring That is because Tour does not tell you about any limitations. You learn about them when you try to upvote or downvote without having sufficient reputation. While not being able to vote will not get you in any trouble, other uninformed actions may - and this is the core issues here. Users are not presented with rules, they don't even know there are rules, let alone punishments.

Comment: This survey seems to show that people should demonstrate more research, put in more effort and formulate more clearly when posting question and answers if they want to avoid downvotes. If the goal of further studies is to make people more aware of that, I'm all for it. I hope you can come up with good ideas. Some larger singposts maybe ("If you do not show research, you'll get downvoted!"). Maybe a brainstorming on meta would also help. For a moment I thought that the company simply wants to abolish downvotes, when the downvote survey was announced. Luckily this does not seem to be the case.

Comment: @PM2Ring I regularly click them on sites where I don't have 125 reputation but content is bad/wrong, so that at the very least it is recorded in the site data published each year.

Comment: @OlegValter We won't be sharing the raw open-ended responses. (Our researcher didn't feel comfortable because there's some bad language.) I've already included the main takeaways from the open ends in the writeup.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone 3% of people who saw the modal took the survey and 52.7% dismissed it

Comment: @KevinB The monthly Site Satisfacton Survey is advertised at the top of the page. (I am confirming internally whether it also appears in the left nav, where Teams advertising appears.) It is probably luck of the draw in your case -- we heavily sample traffic to ensure we only get 1K responses from anonymous users and 1K from registered users.

Comment: @AnitaTaylor Were other stats on the dismissal rate recorded? In other words, do we know whether a certain rep. group was more likely to take/ dismiss the survey over another?

Comment: @zcoop98 We didn't track dismissal rate by rep level, but we did track anonymous vs. registered. 53% of anonymous users dismissed the survey vs. 50.2% of registered users. Registered users were much more likely to complete the survey (16.3%) vs. anonymous users (0.4%).

Comment: @AnitaTaylor Thanks! One more question– [The intro](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406791/downvotes-survey-results/406793#who-took-the-survey) mentions that "*56.5% [of respondents] actually had the downvote privilege,*" but the table right below it shows that 63.1% of respondents had 125+ reputation.  Am I misunderstanding that first statement, or is there a mistype here somewhere?

Comment: @zcoop98 The 56.5% includes both anonymous and registered users. The table that shows reputation bands only includes registered users, as they are the only ones with reputation.

Comment: @AnitaTaylor "we did track anonymous vs. registered" - just for clarification purposes: did the research track the first dismissal only, or the percentage can include those who were presented the survey multiple times and chose to dismiss the survey?

Comment: @AnitaTaylor "We won't be sharing the raw open-ended responses" -  that's a pity, I think we here on MSO can take some profanity :) It would also be useful in determining whether the claims of DVs being a hostile act have a substance behind them. "included the main takeaways" - so, nothing especially interesting in those responses then (unexpected reasons, prevalence of emotional response, etc)?

Comment: @AmirhosseinTarmast - so, you are basing a statement about the *most common* case on the experience of one person on one (or a small set) of questions, am I correct?

Comment: @OlegValter On the raw responses, people mostly elaborated on the quality theme -- e.g., they were downvoting because an answer was incorrect or a question was homework, which I've summarized above. Nothing else was a major factor.

Comment: @AnitaTaylor Would it make sense to publish the data you have gathered after removing all person related information? That way everyone can analyse and tell a story based on their own background. Usually when this kind of data gets analysed and reported from one party it does not tell the whole story as statistics are dependent on who is telling the story.

Comment: @AnitaTaylor - eh, thanks for engaging anyway (despite the high chance when the numbers confirm what you already know that they fell prey to confirmation bias, it is nice to see that people at least follow the rules or think this is *expected* of them to follow when downvoting)! To second mike here, please do consider the request (or escalate to those who make the decision) of making an anonymized and/or redacted data available - regardless of the outcome, it is an invaluable data source for anyone curious enough to spend some time doing data "munching".

Comment: I also have the feeling that quesionts that have a few downvotes already, are easily downvoted more by people visiting the question without even reading it or making up their own mind. It's like, oh so many downvotes, this must be a bad question, let's downvote also.... and then they continue to another question

Comment: I don't believe these results represent what I see.  I see people down voting because they don't like the formatting of the article, the paragraph sizes, because the writer is new to the system, because they don't use code blocks etc etc.  Also the comments left behind are  not on topic and often relate to their pet peeve on the system.  All of which does not help resolve the main question/issue.  The system is not balanced in that way.  People without rep can't respond and get the these behaviors fixed.  Instead people with rep rip on those that don't have rep.

Comment: @Keith - the question I ask everyone: care to give a couple of examples? I am willing to go through each and every one of them and assess whether they represent the problem at hand or not. Anecdotal evidence is, in my opinion, the worst kind of rhetoric there is when talking about a problematic practice. P.s. "without rep can't respond" - not true in the slightest.  A user can *always* respond on their posts and they *always* can edit their posts regardless of the rep.

Comment: oh, and one more thing: please, **stop highjacking the post about the results of the downvotes survey to further one's own agenda**

Comment: @OlegValter - This isn't rhetoric, it is based on real sitings of issues.  Of course you can respond but the users down vote you for that as well.  IOW:  You can't really respond. This isn't about an agenda either.  I'm suggesting the current implementation of downvoting is dysfunctional and isn't productive for a well run web site.  Lastly, if you're not interested in taking feed back while you are providing results then what can I say.  Being open is part of a survey process.  BTW:  I spent almost 10 years in marketing research... I know the process.  I am not mad and I am trying to help.

Comment: @Keith, so, can you present these sitings then? I am not trying to dismiss concerns, I *know* there are problems. But what I really dislike is "my word - your word" style of debate. Believe it or not, what you talk about *is not my experience*. But we cannot figure out what's right or wrong because you *assert* something you don't provide *data* for Re: agenda - this wasn't part of the response to you per se, rather to people trying to turn this into a collection of anecdotes "I've been downvoted before, the system is broken".

Comment: Well this space is 2 small :( and spending the next few hours digging up multiple occurrences isn't going to be productive since I'll find a few and then you'll say well it's only a few.  I can only share MY experience with you.  I can't help, if you choose NOT to accept what I say.  I'm to OLD to get into long debates over important things that are dismissed.

Comment: @Keith - one comment and wrapping up to avoid chit-chat: but you, as others, are pretty happy to share the conclusions, right? Without any hint of analyzing the bigger picture. My/your experience is not going to work on a network visited by millions of users that uses free work of a much smaller number of volunteers. We just can't afford talking experience. Note that I am not a proponent of the current system, btw. P.s. please, can we not bring "I am here for X years" and "I am too old for discussion" into this? When you post something, you (an abstract "you") should be ready to defend it.

Comment: same thing one last response.  I am OLD I didn't say I've been here x years and I am not an abstract me.  I am sharing MY experience with the site and not somebody else's.  I can ONLY talk about my own experience and I _AM_ trying to help.  Being abstract works for art not when talking about real issues. HTH!!

Comment: A note for @Keith and others, in case they haven't thought of it this way– your personal experience on the site matters and is meaningful, full stop. As an active member of the community, your contributions and opinions are valuable! *However*, everyone needs to stop and consider the fact that their personal experience is only ever a small slice of the whole picture, and is almost *guaranteed* not to properly represent the whole. If we're going to truly make our site systems better, we can't afford act on anecdotes and hearsay alone, we *have* to act on real data that helps us see the whole.

Comment: Four significant digits, for example, "55.61%", does not make sense (suggesting a level of precision that isn't there). Counting statistics alone give a best-case relative uncertainty of about 3%, thus a maximum number of significant digits of about 2.

Answer (score 112):

I'd really separate question and answer downvotes; they serve fundamentally different purposes. Answer votes determine the order in which answers are shown. Question votes can hide some questions from the front page, but they don't have quite the same effect as answer downvotes. And the reasons for voting on questions and answers are quite different.

I very strongly feel that "sufficient research" and "sufficient effort" are not the same at all. The main issue with a lack of effort is that it results in bad questions that are not answerable. If I don't put in the relevant details, nobody can provide a good answer, which leads to fundamentally flawed questions. "Insufficient research" is just a fancier way of saying the question is too simple. It doesn't mean the question is unanswerable. It just means the user downvoting thinks it isn't worth answering.

This whole experiment is also tainted, as the tooltip tells you why you are supposed to downvote. That doesn't mean the tooltip is right or wrong, but it's been there for a long time and many users know it's the canonical answer to why we downvote.

Comment: The last paragraph is spot on. Self-reported data is usually far from the truth and in this case self-reporting is combined with a pressure toward a canonical (should be) answer.

Comment: Can you clarify why you believe _"Insufficient research is just a fancier way of saying the question is too simple"_? For me,  _"Insufficient research"_ literally means..... "Insufficient research"! For example, if you can find some clear SO duplicate(s), or promising google matches for the question in just a few seconds, that indicates "Insufficient research", regardless of how simple (or not) the question might be.

Comment: @skomisa true enough. A researched question can also be quite bad because research results without an understanding of how they collate can create one chaotic mess of misjudgement and code riddled with shotgun debugging attempts. It's a wonky metric to judge a question by, IMO.

Comment: Another (minor) distinction that's missing: is this downvote to inform other users seeking answers, or other users who are providing answers?

Comment: Something else I'd like to mention is removing 1 reputation for downvoting answers. In my opinion, that should either be removed or applied as well to questions; I'd prefer removed.

Answer (score 84):

Congratulations!

It took you how long to learn what we already know...

Fine. You (the company) insist on doing things the long way.

> Our goal is to help these new users better understand the rules and
> norms of Stack Overflow so that they can participate successfully on
> the platform.

How can users understand the rules better when SO is not even letting them know there are rules, let alone punishments?

> The insights gained from this downvotes survey will help influence our
> approach to user onboarding.

I said it before and I will say it again.

### JUST CLEARLY EXPLAIN THE RULES.

Preferably before people make their first post.

Comment: but... explaining the rules is unkind, can't have that around here

Comment: I was going to post this exact same answer, but you beat me to it.  I suppose I can at least sleep a little easier because [it doesn't seem like they're de-clawing what downvotes are](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/399883/1079354) based on the data that they had to collect.  But I still don't think we're *quite* in the clear yet.

Comment: @Makoto uh... at last, usually you are writing answers I want to write... but usually you also do a pretty good job writing them and they turn out better than the ones I imagined in my head... so maybe I was too fast this time ;)

Comment: To be honest I didn't really feel like shouting at the kids in the yard today.  I'm starting to realize that the advice I'm giving them is propping up their business use case, and I'm *just* considering that it may be time to start charging for that instead of volunteering it.

Comment: @Makoto I don't like shouting, but it feels like this is the only way to get the message through. Maybe, I am wrong. But this is also kind of example, how fine print does not work when people are in hurry trying to solve their problem (when asking questions on SO). If you put something that big in front of them (it does not have to be all caps) I bet that it will not be easily ignored.

Comment: I imagine a big banner for the first three asked questions saying something like "If you do not show your research or put lots of effort in your post, your posts will get heavily downvoted. This is not a joke. Take it seriously..." Then at least they were warned.

Comment: @Trilarion but big banners are bad

Comment: @KevinB Only if they advertise something unrelated ;)

Comment: Re: "JUST CLEARLY EXPLAIN THE RULES." - Well, kind of, but people don't read instructions, do they? Why not, instead, make **a game** out of the rules? You play the game, you pass all the challenges in the game, you complete the game, you are allowed to set up an account. Haven't completed the game? Then you can't set up an account.

Comment: @Rounin Maybe you are right people like games ;) On more serious note, main problem is discoverability of the rules, and even sideline tips on Ask question page are out of focus. Nobody is reading the instructions because they are either well hidden or seem optional... If you have large warning that tells you all bad things that can happen if you don't follow the instructions then people might start reading them. If the don't, well now that is entirely their problem. right now there is still plenty of people willing to follow the rules, if only someone pointed them before they got in trouble

Comment: *"It took you how long to learn what we already know."* Someone probably should have posted proof of why people vote in the announcement post if you didn't want them doing the survey.

Answer (score 76):

I just want to mention that the group of "strugglers" is not homogeneous from my experience. There are two main sub-groups:

- People who lack experience in posting content.
- People who don't take posting on SO seriously.

Users who lack experience try their best to post good content but struggle to get the scope, structure, accessibility of their posts right. These factors get better as the users get familiar with the site by posting and reading more.

Then there are users who don't just lack experience in posting content but also get spelling, grammar and especially formatting wrong. These users often see in SO a forum where anything goes just as long as it's a sort of question/answer.

The best way to help the first group is to give them the room to make experiences.

The best way to help the second group is to make them aware of what kind of quality is expected.

Comment: On SO itself there's a third group: drive-bys who just want an answer to their homework problem, or to someone _else's_ homework problem they're trying to get paid for doing.  They are _also_ counted in your group #2.  The best way to help this third group is to encourage them to piss off and never come back.  If only we could vote for electric shocks through the user's keyboard ...

Comment: @davidbak But, um, that, um, would be, um,... unwelcoming ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @41686d6564 - Yes, indeed.  I'm all in favor of welcoming those who deserve welcoming.  But I'm also asking for the use of judgement in that.  There are some who don't belong, who don't want to make an effort to belong, on whom effort to make them belong is not just wasted but impossible and actually detrimental.  And, frankly, at least on SO itself, it isn't even a tough choice with close calls.  These people are _obvious_.  (But actually, I suspect you're ... kidding around ... eh?)

Comment: @davidbak Of course, I was being sarcastic :)

Comment: Many posts have much bigger more fundamental issues than spelling, grammar and formatting which can't relatively easily be fixed by some random editor. Poor spelling, grammar and formatting also doesn't always mean they don't take posting seriously. They may just not consider those specific factors to be particularly important (which I agree with if the post is easy enough to fix), they may not be proficient at English, they may not understand formatting (which may be due to laziness, confusion or feeling intimidated) or they may lack the natural attention-to-detail to easily avoid such issues

Comment: @BernhardBarker it may sound harsh, but people who “just not consider those specific factors to be particularly important” should most probably stop programming and get a different job. Compilers do not forgive poor spelling and grammar, wrong formatting will lead to logical errors, and not paying attention to details will backfire. We should not support people who think “programming” means “dumping word diarrhea on Stackoverflow and copy whatever code that gives in return into my editor”.

Comment: @BernhardBarker The onus is **always** on the asker to make their question *as easy to answer as possible*. If they aren't doing that for any reason, **that is not our problem**, nor should it be. Stack Overflow does not exist to teach fundamental basics of programming, never mind those of English.

Comment: @Holger My point is good questions are rare and valuable and salvaging good underlying questions or answers is, in my opinion, more important than berating or turning away a poster for a few easily-fixable issues. If the poster really is as bad at programming as you seem to imply, then there should be more than enough issues with the underlying question or answer to get rid of it without considering the misspelling of a few words. We are a content-based, not user-based, site, so we should focus on the quality of the question, not whether the user would make a good programmer.

Comment: @IanKemp What's the logic behind putting the responsibility of high quality of a post entirely on a poster? If we are striving to ["build a library of detailed answers to every* question about programming"](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and if there are people willing to fix issues in posts (which there are), then it seems only logical to allow posts with some spelling, formatting and other issues we can fix. One could perhaps argue it's not sustainable, but there are much worse issues with posts, so it's like cutting off a finger because of a tiny cut while ignoring the hole in your chest.

Comment: @BernhardBarker We’re not talking about misspelling of a few words, that can be fixed with a plain edit. You were talking about “poor spelling, grammar *and* formatting” and that the author “may just not consider those specific factors to be particularly important” … “*due to laziness, confusion or feeling intimidated*”. I’ve never seen a poorly written question due to the author “feeling [too] intimidated” to write a good question. Rather, it’s the opposite, the author being overconfident that dropping shit and yelling “gimme the code” was fine.

Comment: @Holger Again, if the question has no value and/or is off topic, then that in itself is a reason to get rid of it. Good or bad spelling, grammar and/or formatting wouldn't change that. If, on the other hand, the only issue with a question is spelling, grammar and/or formatting, then it can indeed be fixed with a plain edit. Unless the spelling, grammar and/or formatting is so bad that you can't reasonably figure out what's being asked, but then the question is unclear and *that* would be the reason to get rid of it (not directly because of the spelling, grammar and/or formatting).

Comment: I don't expect consistent, proper writing so much as I expect writing that is *coherent*. I'm somewhat forgiving of poor spelling and grammar, and punctuation as long as it's not .... exaggerated ..... like this !!!! A lot of incredibly messy code still compiles as long as it doesn't break any grammar rules, particularly in the majority of languages where whitespace is largely insignificant. But when someone is struggling to write coherent sentences, I don't want to say they're not *welcome* on the site so much as that we simply don't have the resources to support them every time.

Comment: There are many incoherent questions that get cleared out each day, but they don't make up some overwhelming percentage of daily incoming content. Most content I see each day is more or less readable, only that not enough research effort and understanding are demonstrated most of the time. I really couldn't care less that a question was poorly written to begin with *if it clearly shows the asker has put thought into the question and understands what they are trying to do*. That's where edits come in.

Comment: To be completely transparent, I used to be as snobbish about poorly written questions for the longest time. I'm more tolerant of them now, even though I do wonder why the majority of questions are poorly written and there aren't more people who can write decently well posting questions.

Comment: There's another group that's missing from this Answer. It's the group that only asks questions about rare situations that end up being unpopular due to their rarity. They have evidence of their research, have put good effort into the question with lots of details and proper formatting and even proper English, yet get negative feedback due to how few people actually understand the situation.

Comment: @computercarguy I find that hard to believe, unless the information was presented in a way that *looks* off-topic. Well-written questions about rare situations are far more likely to get no feedback (and there isn't really anything that can be done about that) than negative feedback.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery, you can believe what you like, but I've seen it fairly often, and not just in my own questions.

Comment: @computercarguy Care to provide some examples?

Comment: @JohnMontgomery, two of my own questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58274307/member-object-equalsobject-object-cannot-be-accessed-with-an-instance-refer and this one was roombaed for downvotes before I asked it again https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66374508/how-to-disable-compiler-warnings-in-only-generated-code-without-editing-files. I wish I could provide more, but it's not like I keep a list around. Take a look at the 2nd to last comment by jrh on the Q of that last one. They've seen similar situations, too.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery, found one from another user https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61814688/how-to-add-an-aud-claim-to-access-token

Comment: One of the big problems with niche scenarios is not enough people who see it being able to provide positive feedback. So they are far more sensitive to the noise in voting.

Comment: Having less actual off-topic questions would probably help those questions as like in smaller tags and the earlier days of SO, people are more likely to give it benefit of the doubt when questions like that are a higher proportion of the overall questions.

Comment: And the language barrier. There are several users I can think of who post the same poor quality questions again and again, even when given so much help to improve.... these are often users where I suspect language is a barrier; though there are some who say, "I will do x or y next time", but never do.... those latter cases would ofc be in your second group.

Comment: @computercarguy If you were to ask me how you could've improved [your first question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58274307), I'd probably say you should post a [(minimal) complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that can be run by anyone with a description of the behaviour you want. A title phrased as a question that is specific to your issue (i.e. doesn't equally apply to the similar question you linked to) may also help others see the difference between your question and the linked one and avoid "drive-by" downvoters (even if error-as-title is useful).

Comment: @computercarguy It probably also doesn't help that you kept arguing with someone who appears to have correctly pointed out the problem (but couldn't tell you how to fix it because there wasn't a complete example to work with), but I wouldn't know whether the downvotes came before or after that. I would disagree that the compiler "got confused": it only told you why it couldn't use the method you "told it" to use (based on your incorrect code). In this case you didn't actually want to use that method, so the error is misleading, but it couldn't really have figured out what you were trying to do

Comment: @computercarguy It's also a question that might be really hard to ask and answer in a way that would be helpful to others. You're basically passing the wrong thing as a parameter to the method, but what you need to pass will depend entirely on your code. Some people might downvote for this reason, which may or may not be justifiable, but either way I don't think there's really a way to avoid those downvotes (except to just not ask such questions at all). The "best" error questions are about how to generally fix it as opposed to specific to some code (but you can't just randomly ask those).

Comment: May you guys stop using the comment-section as a chat? The latest comments are not even directly related to my post.

Comment: For the second group, the underlying reason is (in most cases) the minimum-effort attitude. They don't actually lack skills; they just couldn't care less about their readers. (OK, ['care less' is](https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/754-the-tie-between-ann-landers-and-could-care-less/id173429229) [muddled](https://www.podtrac.com/pts/redirect.mp3/media.blubrry.com/grammargirl/traffic.libsyn.com/grammar/gg_754.mp3), but it should be clear from context.)

Comment: @BernhardBarker, how come people always say "the best way to avoid DVs is to not ask Qs" on a site where the whole point is to ask Qs? BTW, I argued that someone on the deleted Q had the exact opposite advice, so they both couldn't be correct. Who do I believe? The one with the loudest argument? I think the compiler "got confused" because it only spit out one reason for the error, when there's actually multiple possible reasons. Isn't SO filled with Q's about unclear or misleading compiler errors? And, like akuzminykh said, this isn't the place to discuss what you think it wrong with my Q's.

Comment: @computercarguy I just pointed out the simple fact that not posting a question avoids downvotes on the question you didn't post. What you do with that fact is up to you. I have no idea what "opposite advice" you're talking about. You provided examples of questions that are "unpopular due to their rarity", implying there are no other major reasons people might downvote them for. I simply provided a few other reasons. And a few of our most popular questions are about weird rare issues. Also, if you link to your questions on Meta, you risk people discussing them.

Comment: @BernhardBarker, and I pointed out the simple fact that not posting a question avoids getting an answer, which is the whole point of this site. https://www.bridging-the-gap.com/the-only-stupid-question-is-the-one-you-dont-ask/ And providing feedback on Q's is supposed to be done on the Q, not the comments of an unrelated post. You have the RP to know that. BTW, "few of our most popular questions" are also generally over a decade old and have gained "popularity" through age. By definition, if they were actually rare, they wouldn't be popular.

Comment: @computercarguy It seems like you don't quite realise that the optimal action with only one goal in mind (avoiding downvotes) might not be the optimal action with only another goal in mind (getting an answer), and how you prioritise those and other goals may affect what you choose to do, and this site isn't the only place to get an answer, nor can you get every answer here. "By definition, if they were actually rare, they wouldn't be popular" - well, no, I'm talking about 2 different things. The issue is rare. The question is popular. Neither implies anything about the other "by definition".

Comment: *I do wonder why the majority of questions are poorly written and there aren't more people who can write decently well posting questions* - outside of emerging technologies, I think the key factor is that most of the common questions have already been asked and answered.  And (my hypothesis) that there's a correlation between 1. ability to write clearly (and formulate the problem into an SO question) with  2. ability (and willingness) to search for an answer before bothering other people to ask them to spend their time on it.  i.e. general competence and/or courtesy.

Answer (score 23):

An interesting question to ask would have been "Have you ever gone back to a question you downvoted, and removed the downvote?"

I feel that downvotes are actually more destructive than closing a question.

If I downvote, that downvote stays. I have the option to remove it if the question is edited, but really I'm not going to go back and check all the low-quality questions I've ever seen. There's currently no prompt to do so, and so no easy method of doing it.

The idea is that if the question is edited to be a better question, it might start attracting upvotes. But when it has a negative score it is already less visible, and when it isn't a new question, it is also less visible, so I doubt that often happens in reality.

However, if I close a question, one of the review queue actions is specifically about reopening closed questions if they've been edited. Even better, you don't rely on the same people who closed a question to reopen it!

Comment: This... is information that SE already have. There are upvotes and unupvotes, downvotes and undownvotes, accept and unaccept events registered in the database.

Comment: Along the lines of "which posts have been edited since I (down)voted", I had a similar thought and discovered that someone had solved this particular problem from the client-side: https://stackapps.com/q/6755/39209. It'd be great if Stack Exchange could incorporate that as a core function. Thought I'd point you to the client-side version in case you're interested.

Comment: I agree with this wise observation by @SpoonMeiser.  Downvotes of questions are typically forever for a decade or more, even long after the question has been drastically improved to be spectacular.

Answer (score 12):

In the case of downvotes on answers, I would love to know the break down of accepted vs top vs everything else of these results. Is the top/accepted answer more likely downvoted in the sample? Do the reasons for downvotes they differ between them? Etc. Basically a contingency table of the position/order of the downvoted answer against all other variables.

Answer (score 8):

Given these findings & goals:

> We are in early discovery on a project to improve new user onboarding (stay tuned for a Meta post). We've identified a subset of users that we call "strugglers." These users actively participate on Stack Overflow, but experience negative outcomes from their actions, such as being downvoted often ...

> Our goal is to help these new users better understand the rules and norms of Stack Overflow so that they can participate successfully on the platform.

If you don't already know about the [Natty bot](https://stackapps.com/questions/7049/natty-bringing-10k-moderation-to-all) in the [SOBotics chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/111347/sobotics), it watches for posts that are in the Answer box but have indications that they're really new Questions. Many of the "Answers" accumulate downvotes before they get reviewed and eventually deleted. That fits the definition of a "struggler" to me and their first experience is obviously a negative one, even without any canned review comments.

My suggestion would be to incorporate the idea behind Natty into Stack Exchange so that if a potential "Answer" scores highly enough as a non-Answer, the user is intercepted with additional guidance on the "rules and norms of Stack Overflow". You'll save grief on the part of the new user *and* among the reviewer community.

Comment: From my experience with clearing Natty's reports, I can say with confidence that the answers that fall into Natty's auto-flagging/commenting category are so poorly written that the author couldn't care less about reading the rules or norms of SO.  I always leave canned comments on such answers but I get positive responses very very rarely. Most people just ignore them.

Comment: Perhaps there's a lower limit then, to the kind of user that participates on SO. Even if the user is blocked from participating, then there's the follow-on benefit to smaller review queues and less-exasperated reviewers.

Comment: False positives might cause confusion. :(

Comment: Understood, and the thresholds/criteria are obviously up to people who are smarter than me, but it seems that the existing bot has a nice scoring mechanism as a starting point.

Comment: Yep true. I think this discussion is similar to this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343065/can-a-machine-be-taught-to-flag-non-answers-and-post-comments-on-them-automatica There are some very good points there.

Comment: We already have that. It doesn't work. People ignore warnings and all information. Sometimes they will apologize but that doesn't stop them from posting a question as an answer.

Answer (score 8):

Having a more detailed image of reasons behind downvotes is useful. But that's just a detailed part of a much bigger image.

I always believed that part of the scope of Stack Overflow is not just about giving/receiving answers, but the learning aspect, both for people asking questions as for those answering.

Being a teacher myself I know this very well: teaching is learning. And a fundamental aspect of teaching is not only point out errors to your students and correct them, but to teach them how to avoid those errors - and learn how to teach that myself.

As answerers, many of us don't just give solutions, but also methods that allow users to not repeat mistakes by explaining the reasons behind good/best practices, not only for the specific subject of the post, but also about related aspects (syntax, implementation optimization, styling/naming conventions, etc.) *and* question making.

The last part is the most sensitive problem for new users.

Long time users are usually experienced enough (with the website and programming in general) to understand the reasons behind downvotes on their own; when in doubt they know they can ask for clarifications in comments, but it's often unnecessary as the question is probably already written in a way that downvoters will probably already comment about it.

To most people (beginners in both programming or SO practices), a downvote is like a bad school grade given without explanation. Most of them even take it very personally (we've all seen new users losing their temper after few questions that take immediate downvotes), and there's often the case of users that delete a downvoted answer and then just create a new one almost identical (which usually results in even more downvotes).

One of the things I teach since the very first lesson is how to deal with mistakes, and the first step is to be able to recognize them. One of the biggest problems with votes and reputation systems is that most of the times the user doesn't know the meaning behind a downvote, the reason for it and how they can improve both the question at hand and their future questions to avoid them. Even if there's often a comment about that, the amount of bad quality questions from new users is so big that even patient people get annoyed and just give up explaining in the long run.

Then, as pointed out, there's the problem that downvotes are often forgotten. I downvote, *a lot*, but I retract as much as possible as soon as the author edits the post in a valid way. But that doesn't happen often: there's no notification, no easy search method, and there is no easy way to find them back. And that gets even worse for niche tags, questions that get very little attention since the beginning and even less after downvotes, so, even after editing, the downvotes remain, the question gets ignored and we're back to the beginning: the user doesn't know what to do, and will probably leave the community or just ask other bad questions again and again.

There's very little point in knowing the specific reasons for which we downvote, if the *target* of those downvotes don't know that. And they should be able to know that **before** they get possibly downvoted.

As a teacher, my job is not to point out mistakes, but to teach how to avoid and deal with them in the first place, **since the very first lesson**.
And I strongly believe that *this* is the main issue here: it *is* our responsibility to give reasons about downvotes, but our role should be to talk about programming issues, not how to ask questions; that is *your responsibility*, to prevent that we even downvote for those reasons.

Comment: What do you teach? Playing musical instruments? What kind of mistakes do your students make?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I primarily teach classical percussions and drums, but also theory and practice in general. There's obviously a high range of mistakes, depending on the age and experience. The most common "practical" mistakes are all related to timing in some way, including wrong notes (which is due to insufficient practice at correct tempos), but, in reality, the most common and important one is, coincidentally, misunderstanding what a mistake is (and how to deal with them), and then not being able to correctly recognize mistakes or *where* they actually reside (not unlike XY problems).

Answer (score 6):

I'm disappointed in the fact that the "I only downvoted" category was not broken down into:

- "I only downvoted, and there was already a comment explaining my reason for the downvote (which I didn't upvote)" vs.
- "I only downvoted, and there was no comment explaining my reason for the downvote".

because the former action is acceptable (though I would recommend against it; one should upvote the comment), while the latter action is IMHO deplorable.

Comment: It looks like you are saying that you find it deplorable to downvote a post without leaving a comment. Users are not required to explain downvotes, just like they are not required to explain upvotes. Why would that be deplorable?

Comment: @MarcoBonelli: An action doesn't have to be forbidden to be deplorable... but to answer your question: If you just downvoted, you haven't helped the author understand what's wrong with their question, and have not opened a path for them to rectify it. It hurts to be downvoted, and silent downvotes, to a newbie user, can feel a bit like a drive-by shooting. So the least we should do is say what's wrong.

Comment: And to be perfectly honest - I hate when people do this to me personally, and I can't guess what bugged them about the question. Like [in this one just now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66688827/nsight-compute-says-file-mismatch-although-its-the-right-file).

Comment: The idea that downvoters should provide feedback imply that they also should just put up with whatever abuse that may come afterwards, all for the sake of assisting a single asker who may or may not be in position to take it constructively. This is not unheard of and should not be neglected. Since votes serve mostly as a signal to everyone who sees the question (as made evident by this survey), a vote already serves its purpose. As for the hurt of receiving downvotes, they should definitely not be hurtful and everyone should take them less personally. We can't say the same for real abuse.

Comment: @E_net4thecopycat: 1. I personally never experienced any abuse after downvoting and explaining my downvote. Certainly, people try to explain/justify, but that's a legitimate part of the editing/review process, isn't it? 2. "This is not unheard of" <- do you have any statistics about the prevalence of this phenomenon? IMHO and to my knowledge, this is negligible. 3. Verbal abuse of downvoters will likely be met with a very negative response from other users and possibly moderators.

Comment: 1. Examples of abuse are not lacking, I have shared some incidents myself around other Meta posts (e.g. [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375548)). I disagree with any abuse being legitimate, because it suggests that the platform cannot sustain a respectful and welcoming environment to contributors. 2. That could be constructed in part from the [heated comment feed](https://higgs.sobotics.org/reports?pageNumber=1&dashboard=1), although it would represent only one form of abuse. From observing these and word of mouth from moderators, it is likely more frequent than revenge downvotes.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I understood point 3. Verbal abuse from downvoters is something I only seldom see. The most common form is from other users towards curators. None of these actions are condoned, of course, but they cause some damage nonetheless.

Comment: @E_net4thecopycat: My point (3.) is that we have community mechanisms for dealing with abusive comments from posters towards curators, which to some extent mitigate the worry or fear of such comments being made. Although, again, I've not experienced this myself.

Comment: @E_net4thecopycat: 1. Anonymous downvotes without a stated cause already constitute a non-welcoming and somewhat disrespectful environment. And indeed, SO is infamous for its downvote culture (albeit not only for anonymous downvotes) - as opposed to other SX websites, where curators are much more likely to make comments and typically delay their downvoting.

Comment: 2. Looking at that comment feed, most are self-deprecating or just use profane words but don't direct them at curators. I see two properly abusive posts over the past day; one of these is quite juvenile and would almost certainly not hit its mark ("I hate you I'm gonna hack you") and the other ("Because you are a something something eating something") is indeed something one would try to avoid, but that too seems to come after an escalating exchange of comments. So I see no examples of a single comment triggering an abusive reply, over the past 24h.

Comment: Still on point 3, from the moment those comments are posted, [the damage is already done](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396581). So it's only natural for people to avoid becoming a target. On 1, I would say it goes both ways. Such a fiery stance against downvoters (esp. without leaving comments) does not at all contribute to reversing this _modus operandi_. For one, shaming those users seems like the perfect way to drive them even further away from the site, and from doing the actions that we don't want to discourage. In other simple words, shaming is not OK.

Comment: Considering other sites in the SE network is not a trivial comparison, given the cheer amount of users and overall traffic on SO, which may definitely influence the nature of interactions (like how the population of big cities may seem less welcoming than those from smaller towns).

Comment: On 2, we cannot just take the last 24h of a relatively calm day and call it representative. Looking just a few days further back, we can see gems such as calling downvoters "perverts", a few of the form _"if you can't answer, shut up"_, "Stupid closing-freaks", and so on. One should not exclude comments which came from escalation, especially because the escalation could have never started to begin with by refraining from leaving a comment.

Comment: @E_net4thecopycat: If you need to go back a few days for examples, then it seems this is a negligible issue. Also, I am guessing that some/most/all of your additional examples are not actually replies to a single downvote-accompanying comment.

Comment: I stand on them not being negligible, because the poor experience after one comment out of dozens is bad enough that it just disincentivizes future commenting. It may be right that not all comments were a consequence of a downvote accompanied by a comment, but users are known to conflate these actions and lash out regardless. Alas, not everyone follows [this advice](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388686/why-shouldnt-i-assume-i-know-who-downvoted-my-post).

Comment: Agree with @einpoklum that a downvote on a question with no explanation, like in his applicably linked example is neither welcoming nor helpful.

Comment: I do agree that downvotes without comment (while being explicitely accepted on SO) are highly irritating. When one of my posts gets one, I immediately delete it, unless I think it really can help the OP. In that case, I give the post a one day maximum delay before deletion.

Comment: @SergeBallesta: You delete your own answers because of opaque downvote? :-(

Comment: @einpoklum: yes I do. Fortunately I do not do it very often. After all an answer that has only downvotes cannot have a great value. And without a comment explaining what is bad, I cannot hope improving it. So what else could I do?

Comment: "After all an answer that has only downvotes cannot have a great value" <- Oh, but that's not true. It could be downvoted for various flaws while still having values; or it could simply be misunderstood; or it's an opinionated answer downvoted by people who disapprove of its perspective. You should trust your own judgement and let your answer stand. Let the OP be the judge of whether it helps them or not.

Comment: @einpoklum - I'd also say let the *time* be the judge of the merits of the answer. So what if it got a single downvote (maybe even multiple) if one is adamant they are correct? After a while, the dust settles, and good answers usually start accumulating upvotes.

Comment: @OlegValter: That's only sometimes true. For niche questions, months and years can pass between votes. But yes, time is also a factor.

Comment: @einpoklum - true, can't argue with that (although it was my understanding that obscure tags usually have a small number of active maintainers who usually engage on most questions just because the volume is so low. While with popular tags it is usually easier to vote and move on - not unlike the difference in dynamic between cities and villages [I think someone brought it up before])

Answer (score -3):

> Study finds, most of the respondents say they use a feature as it's supposed to be used.

Not surprising. Not sure what could have come out of that survey with those options. So... we now know that we know.

In other news, [Karl Ranseier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTL_Samstag_Nacht) is dead.

Comment: Why is collecting data to support something we "know" a bad thing?

Comment: They could have done something useful with that money. It's not like the survey actually left room for another outcome. You ask people that clicked a button whether they did it because they wanted to click the button for the official reasons for clicking the button. Most of them say yes. About as useful as asking pedestrians why they walk on green. You will find most like their life enough to prefer not getting run over by a car. Data? Sure. Data that is supporting any kind of action or any new insight? No. And the cost was not 0, so... it could have been spent on not finding out the obvious.

Comment: Collecting the data to support our claims is not wrong, but what is uncertain is how does this help us in making further decisions. It feels like the company is back to square one.

Comment: if "Why did you downvote" would have been the only question, that might be true. But the findings about who the downvote is targeted to (op, other readers), is something I personally find rather interesting. This could be the basis for developing a better workflow for cases where the downvote is targeted for op instead for future readers.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if I took all the number in the report and shuffled them randomly, wouldn't you be able to say exactly the same as you just did? That's what I mean... it's meaningless.

Comment: Not many people will be as dead as Karl, I guess ;)

Comment: @nvoigt sometimes people with management power to make decisions is simply so blind of what's going on down there and so unaware of the reality of the community, that the only way to explain them why is downvoting a problem and why something should be done to address it, is by showing them a nice Powerpoint with beautiful charts showing how many people in SO thought the question needed more detail. That's probably why they needed a survey to answer such an obvious question.

Comment: This is the only answer that deals with the shortcomings of the survey. (the downvotes are no surprise) No methodology was explained what error rate was expected from those who downvoted for "Sour Grapes" reasons, but would answer the survey by picking the most convenient answer. There is no rhyme or reason for many downvotes of 100% technically correct answers by 100K rep users, or the daily occurrence of the "Me too" downvotes that pile up where none or one would be all that is warranted. Glad you are looking at the issue, but as with most efforts, it misses a large part of the problem.

Comment: From *[RTL Samstag Nacht](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTL_Samstag_Nacht)*: *"Karl Ranseier was a recurring character featured in fake news reports* ***telling about his death*** *at the end of each episode. The name Karl Ranseier has become a catchphrase in Germany that has led to its own joke category of Ranseiers which are in widespread usage outside of the comedy origin."*

Comment: @Dharman What if it is back to square one?

Answer (score -6):

It feels like SO knows it needs to change, but it doesn't know how. It looks like many people don't agree on this.

My understanding is that downvoting is mostly "you've wasted my time by not spending yours wisely" or "you're not only not contributing anything useful - you're actively making things worse".

I don't have an answer, but I'm not sure the results of a survey qualify as a question, so I'm just going to speak my mind as a newcomer.

I'm kind of shocked at the mentality of a lot of the comments here. Seeing some fairly negative comments with dozens/hundreds of upvotes makes me question whether an *upvote* survey to assess the health and sanity of the SO community might be as/if not more informative.

Don't take this personally. As a newcomer I'm learning from all of you how I should behave. But some of what I'm seeing doesn't look healthy, sustainable or constructive.

Comment: Perhaps a link to those posts rather than the link you provided to something unrelated (and political) would be more constructive?

Comment: interesting you post this. Nowhere in my post have I suggested that downvotes are bad, ineffective or should be removed. In fact I made no pejorative comment about downvoting whatsoever. And you’ve twice now suggested I need to research this - when clearly you’ve mistaken the point that I actually made - and lead the charge for downvoting my answer. You’ve been aggressive, offtopic, unnecessarily political and then apologetic. this answer is my own form of research. thanks for contributing :)

Comment: Hm... Yeah, you are right, I re-read and realized that I misunderstood your answer. I have deleted my comments. Sorry.

Comment: Unexpected and pretty unnecessary. No need for apologies. Pay it forward, not backward. A constructive exchange I feel, nonetheless.

Comment: Wonder how many downvotes can be attributed to “I misunderstood / overreacted” - the survey here doesn’t consider it. My point here is that upvoting can be weaponised in the same manner as downvoting - but neither are inherently destructive - it’s purely down to the intentions of the community member. Upvoting can be used to entrench both negative and positive behaviours - same as downvoting. Really obvious here on Meta. Seems like this is where people just take out their frustrations on each other where they care less about rep. like an uncomfortable work party where coworkers are drunk

Comment: Meta already receives a fair share of accusations of toxicity for things which can actually be quite reasonably justified. Presenting concrete examples of comments which you find put the sanity of the commenters to question would definitely help clarify this answer.

Comment: Agreed, thanks for highlighting this. I clearly feel comfortable enough to speak up but not comfortable enough to point fingers directly and engage or directly provoke conflict with some senior members when they are gathered in groups and upvoting each other like high fives. I’m comfortable enough having this post being a perfect demonstration of the issues with experienced members completely misinterpreting the sentiment of a post and causing a downvote pile on. It’s not particularly useful to have the comments that were made deleted. But evidences the point well.

Comment: You don't, nor are supposed to, confront directly with users, but to show expressions which in your opinion are heavily problematic. High rep users, despite some folklore outside the network, are not above the rules of proper conduct. On the other hand, witch hunting and finger pointing isn't condoned either.

Comment: Regardless, what seemingly happened here at best was _one_ person misunderstanding the sentiment of this answer. It does not imply that the surge of downvotes came in light of an equivalent interpretation. For what it's worth, stating that what is going on here _" doesn't look healthy, sustainable or constructive"_, without any evidence and without being clear of what part of the exchange you were referring to, would be enough of a reason to downvote.

Comment: Thanks, that’s great clarity. Your perspective here helped me to understand Meta a little better. I see now and agree. Nothing on SX should be without evidence - and that’s the strength of the platform.