# Privilege achieved without meeting the reputation goal

Tags: support, privileges, a-b-testing

So, currently I have 558 reputation on my SO [account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10155936/saurabh-p-bhandari). To get this privilege **"See votes,expandable usercard"**, I need 1000+ rep as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user). However, I noticed that I can click on the score of any post to see the votes anyways for any question. I think its a bug because previously I wasn't able to do it.

Also recently my Q&A [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58327104/10155936) was downvoted (no reason given). But when I visit the page, it says 0 score even though the actual score is -1 (as recorded in my SO account's actions section). What am I missing here?

**Note**: For the above question, I can still see the actual score by clicking on it, however a few hours ago it actually showed -1 and now it just shows 0 (only after clicking the score, it expands to 0 and -1)

Comment: I bet [the downvote count experiment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390178/new-popup-message-when-voting-on-a-question) has more bugs they expected...

Comment: Yes, but this is not a bug @alexei

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quoting myself:

> - You can see the real up/down vote counts at any time by clicking the score while viewing a post - **even if you haven't earned [the Established User privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user)**. You will need to be logged in to access this however.

This means you're in one of the test groups for [our little experiment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390178/new-popup-message-when-voting-on-a-question/390179#390179) - so congratulations, and thank you for helping us test the foundations of this venerable system!

Enjoy it while you can though; this goes back in the box in less than two weeks.

Comment: Classic case of privilege escalation !!, thank you for the answer

Comment: I hope next time I get a notification about such experiments, oh wait I don't think you want the users to know (it is part of the test) I guess

Comment: Eh... We were kinda hoping that maybe a lot of folks wouldn't notice, but at SO's scale that still means a lot of folks *do* notice. Which is ok - we built in lots of helpful messaging - but maybe the "no announcement" thing was a bit too optimistic. Live 'n' learn. Well. Ideally.