# Can we please show negative votes for red flags?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, flags, spam, a-b-testing

It's weird to see 0 votes on a spam post. Any alternative suggestion? I am not against the change and welcome new users, but spam posts should be an  exception. Is there any way to prevent seeing a score of 0 on posts with a spam flag?

**Please don't treat spam as a new user.**

[It's not a duplicate of this one.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390178/new-popup-message-when-voting-on-a-question-answer)

I understand it's an experiment, but don't support spam in the name of an **experiment** please.

Comment: Note that this experiment is *limited in time*, and at this point in time there is no point in asking for new features around something that's really only a temporary hack for now.

Comment: (personally, I find it very annoying having to remember to look at actual scores when moderating, so I otherwise agree that this kind of request is important *if negative post score hiding were ever to become the norm*)

Comment: Martijn's first comment applies. But the thing is, we don't know if something is spam until it's sufficiently flagged as such. And once it is ... well, it's gone. But for now, wait for the test to be over.

Comment: @MartijnPieters in older times I would make a feature request that system wouldn't hide negative score from moderators and I would expect this implemented reasonably quickly

Comment: @Shree: *I am not request new features*: apologies for the confusion then, but you tagged this with [meta-tag:feature-request].

Comment: And I have an actual objection to this request: if this was implemented, then anyone that wanted to 'expose' the vote count on a post would only have to flag it as spam. Whether or not it is actually spam. Either we treat all post scores the same or we don't.

Comment: @MartijnPieters from my reading of this, the OP wants to show the negative vote from spam flags only, so if someone flags a normal post as spam, the post score which is at 0, would get to -1 and not show the vote count. _That said_, I would be concerned about this because it would make it clear that certain posts have received red flags and not just downvotes, and thereby expose flagging information to normal users.

Comment: Side note: Whether one should downvote spam post or just flag it is open question as far as I remember (may find discussion at some point): Downvoting moves it away from home page potentially preventing it to collect needed 5/6 flags and "spam" flag eventually will add extra downvote anyway... One other hand it usually low research/unclear posts deserving downvotes...

Answer (score 3):

We're not going to be making any other changes to the experiment while it is running, which only has another week to run anyways. We'll consider all the odd scenarios during our analysis afterwards and during any conversations for further experiments, if those ever come about.