# Why can I see vote counts without ever having had 1000 reputation?

Tags: bug, privileges

According to [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user) on privileges, I need to have 1000 reputation to see vote counts.

I never had more than 1000 reputation on this account. Right now I am at 900. Despite this, if I click on the vote score, I get to see the vote counts. Cropped screenshot proof:

[image]

Why can I see vote counts?

Comment: It's part of the new test for hiding vote counts that are too low. You are given the privilege to see breakdowns even if you wouldn't normally do.

Comment: _"You can see the real up/down vote counts at any time by clicking the score while viewing a post - even if you haven't earned the Established User privilege."_ - [Shog9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/390179/1835379)

Comment: Oh ok. I didn't know about that experiment and its rules. Maybe keep this question open though? It's probably more likely to be found by people who google this question. If you write an answer I will accept it.

Comment: There are [few other questions linked to the original](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/390178). The experiment will finish soon (next week, I think), so I'm not sure we need an open question for this. However, if anything, I agree that the experiment could have been more clear, as evidenced by the number of questions we've had for it. Perhaps granting the vote breakdown privilige could have been better announced like, sending a notification or at least having a popup the first time you use it.

Comment: Don't wait to get to 1000, see vote counts now: https://stackapps.com/questions/3082/view-vote-totals-without-1000-rep?rq=1

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this question being closed as a duplicate. It is now a signpost to the question where most questions about that experiment are answered.

Comment: @rene That would be too easy. I enjoy the struggle of getting that privilege without cheating. Otherwise I would not have filed this bug ;)

Comment: Do all the downvotes mean I should delete this question? Seems like a bad idea since then it can't be found via Google while the experiment runs. If the downvotes mean that I should know better than asking this in the first place, how was I supposed to know this behavior was part fo a two-week experiment? If the question was unclear, please tell me more specifically what you mean.

Comment: Don't worry for the downvotes, and you were indeed not supposed to know about this experiment (this is at least the 10th question on the subject, with good reason)