# Attempting to downvote a -3 post on Teams makes the score display as -1

Tags: bug, status-completed, voting, stack-overflow-for-teams, a-b-testing

I am in the -1 group in the current Stack Overflow experiment.

On the Charcoal Team, there is [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/c/charcoal/q/36/98). It has -3 score and vote count +2/-5. I have six reputation there, and thus can't downvote it. However, when I try to downvote it, I get just the normal "you can't downvote" warning and the displayed score changes to -1 until I reload! The shown vote count stays correct.

When I upvote, the score also becomes -1; however, when I reload or view the vote counts it is shown correctly.

This happens on desktop, responsive mobile, and the mobile site.

This is a bug report, and completely not a duplicate of [New popup message when voting on a question/answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/390178/9986421). This is also [confirmed by a Community Manager](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390483/attempting-to-downvote-a-3-post-on-teams-makes-the-score-display-as-1#comment735309_390483)

Comment: It’s definitely an actual, separate bug. Please don’t dupe it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should be fixed now. Thanks for the report!

Comment: Thank you for doing this so quickly! It works great now!