# Score -1 when logged in, -3 when not?

Tags: bug

I just noticed that [this question (which may be closed when you read it)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58509799/fnord) has a score of -1 when I'm logged in, but -3 when not.

Why is that? Why is the score displayed differently depending on login?

I've heard that the score is supposed to be displayed as no worse than -1 so as not to seem *harshly* disapproving to the poor asker. (Good idea. A score of -3 and *these five people closed …* can sound rather harsh.) I tagged this as bug because of the -3 and that hearsay.

(Note: [The other question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390178) asks why a negative score isn't displayed, and the answers include variations of "it's displayed for some people". My question is *why* it sometimes *is* displayed. I particularly wonder why it's displayed to the asker when not logged in.)

Comment: TL;DR: there's 3 groups, A see 0 instead of -3, B see -1 instead of -3, C see -3. you're in group B when logged I think

Comment: ^ Additionally, from the proposed dupe: *"You will only see this if you are logged into the site."*

Comment: I suppose that if you're not logged-in then you can't vote (or easily find your question back) so don't have to be lied to.  The experiment ends today, hopefully this all becomes but a bad memory.

Comment: Hopefully this was the last one. If we learned one thing from these kind of experiments, then that it will cause a lot of confusion among users and the UI should explain it better (maybe even linking to a suitable meta post).