# Delay display of down votes that don't offer a suggestion

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, downvotes, new-users, downvote-reason

Down votes that don't offer a suggestion make the user experience more "Negative".

I suggest delaying the display of such votes ( Or just barring them ).

This also fits well with SOs overall quality model.  We have guidelines for people to write good questions.  This encourages good questions.

SO can have a popup that says "Comments without feedback will be delayed 5 minutes before being made available."  This way if the user really cares about their feedback / vote, they will provide comments.  This is good for both reviewers and the ones posting questions.

In order to incorporate the results of this experiment:
[Why can I no longer see that a post has a negative score?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390178/why-can-i-no-longer-see-that-a-post-has-a-negative-score)

SO could display downvotes if for example a post collects 3 or more down votes within 2 minutes.  This filters out the the users who down vote the question simply because the bar is too high for them.

I think if you look at the general history of down votes without an explanation, you'll see that they are usually cancelled out later by up votes.

This would lead to a more pleasant user experience.

SO could also delay the display of the down vote without explanation to the original poster but others could see it.

Here's an example of a question that immediately got a down vote (Without any explanation as usual) and to which I had to find the answer myself.  Angular did not provide any error detection and just failed silently:

[Angular resolver not resolving?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59447093/angular-resolver-not-resolving)

And another example that had a minus one until I came across it and voted it up:

[How to bind an click event for mat-step-header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57429466/how-to-bind-an-click-event-for-mat-step-header)

[image]

Comment: No.  The votes are not for the poster.  They are for the future readers.

Comment: I know you are saying "delaying", but you also mention "just barring them". The dupe refers to that comment. And the general feeling.

Comment: There are users that don't understand a question.  When they don't understand it they down vote it because they don't understand it.  I can provide examples.  Delay would prevent that type of activity.

Comment: usually cancelled by upvotes?! can I please get data on that? This feels like a very broad, unfounded statement (oh and on the "people downvote what they don't understand too.... cause I dunno how **you** get data on why people vote.... but I can't)

Comment: If one of my questions got downvoted, I'd like to know, because perhaps I'd know why myself and I could do something about it. Hiding this information is probably not good for question quality.

Comment: I agree with you @Patrice.  You receive down votes without any explanation and then 3 minutes later it's cancelled by an up vote.  It's kind of like a slap in the face and then 3 minutes later someone walks by and gives you a nice warm massage towel.

Comment: SO could also delay the display of the down vote without explanation to the original poster but others could see it.

Comment: @Ole I'm saying the opposite of that. I am saying your "usually cancelled by upvotes" is incorrect (and asking for data for you to prove it). Also... why make it easier for the original poster? Stack was **never** for the one poster.

Comment: SO could easily run analytics on this and determine how often this happens.  I think you will see hundreds of thousands of instances where something is down voted and then within a short period upvoted.

Comment: @Patrice we will know for sure once we look at the data.  SO has all this data and they can run the analytics on it and determine whether it's worth considering.

Comment: @Ole We often call those "pity upvotes". When those happen, they suck, because they do great harm to community curation efforts.

Comment: @Ole so... "I have an unfounded theory. You look into it, and change all your site if I'm correct". Kind of a tall order, when you think about it. I don't think much will happen on your request :/. For such a fundamental change, there will need to be more than a "hunch"

Comment: Or we could call them "Smart upvotes" because they are made by people that can understand the question and are not frustrated that they can't.

Comment: @Patrice I agree.  It took a long time for SO to become more friendly to new users.  Finally they got around to instituting policies that put assertions like "Pity upvotes" in check.

Comment: We could call them "trendy giraffes", but a rose by any other name would still smell... well, not sweet.

Comment: Hehe - Cool - As long as we give them animal names it's cute :)

Comment: @Ole funny how you agree, without agreeing. But whatever. the point I am making, is that without **data** proving what you say, Stack won't have a big incentive to do that. It's a **lot** of effort to change something that maybe doesn't even need changing. Cause one user says "I think it's that". Feels..... like a very inefficient way to handle Feature requests. I think if a user comes in with more than a hunch. Some data, *something* backing it up.... maybe Stack will be more open to listening. Maybe.

Comment: SO has the data.  It's their company and they derive value from making the site more friendly and attractive to everyone.  If they succeed in that we all win.

Comment: About upvotes that "cancel" downvotes: It's quite possible that, in the interim, the OP has provided the missing information or more clarity, thus making the question worthy of an upvote. It's also possible, in such a case, that someone who downvoted later corrected the downvote because the OP reacted. In both cases, the "cancellation" would be a ***result of the downvote***. So I don't think the POV presented here is completely logical...

Comment: There's all sorts of people who make unfounded claims, and can't back them up.  It's your statement; it's on you to back it up.  Expecting someone else to do it is a common tactic, but doesn't really fly...anywhere.  Expect to be called out on it, and show your data.

Comment: It's logical to correct something that is accompanied with a comment seeking better explanation.

Comment: Just like it's logical for someone who has experience in the site to not rehash an already established meta convention without bringing up new arguments. yet here we are...

Comment: SO is evolving.

Comment: sure, so our arguments should evolve too... take in account the new reality, the new goals, the new whatever. Not be a virtual copy paste of a discussion already had

Comment: It's up to SO to analyze their data and make the decision.

Comment: I think the fact that they have declined every request to make downvote comments mandatory for years is telling @Ole...

Comment: So, you're just going to make the statement, and refuse to back it up?  Okay...but you're not going to gain any traction that way.  It weakens your argument to the point of uselessness.

Comment: If the data says that the feature will make SO more friendly they should do it.

Comment: ["You have it backwards, I think..."](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255019/839601)

Comment: strongly related (possibly even a duplicate): [Why can I no longer see that a post has a negative score?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/390178/839601) TL;DR: this was tested for about half a month and results turned out rather disappointing

Answer (score 17):

Please don't.

As a reader, I very much appreciate knowing what other people think of the question before I read it. It would greatly lessen *my* experience if I find out that even though people were trying to warn me that a question is probably not worth my time the platform decided to keep that signal hidden for hours.

Comment: If they are trying to warn you then they could easily provide an explanation of what they are trying to warn you about.

Comment: @Ole Reading (as well as writing) an explanation is time-consuming. There are too many people who start asking questions without ever reading the site guidelines. No reason not to DV in such cases.

Comment: You assume that I'm interested in opening every question @Ole. I am not. I won't read the explanations, even if they are there. I have lists with hundreds of questions in front of me - thousands if you consider that I'm active in multiple sites. I just want to be able to pick a couple every day that will help me learn something new.

Comment: Cindy - That's a good point.

Comment: The next question is - Does your point matter?  In other words does SO run into a workload constraint if they only allow down votes with accompanied comments?

Comment: All these arguments (and more) are discussed in the duplicate, @Ole.  We're all kinda tired of having to repeat them over and over.  Please read it.

Comment: There's zero data analysis in that post.

Comment: There's zero data analysis in your post

Comment: So you see my point.  If SO is happy with their current revenue level and does not really care about the user experience - then don't do the data analysis.  If they care about the user experience then do the analysis and provide the numbers to all of us.   End of discussion.

Comment: Note: Whenever someone says, "end of discussion", it doesn't mean end of discussion.  It tries to stop critical thought by refusing to engage with any criticism. It does end any chance of reasonable debate, though.

Comment: We can debate whether the sky is clear all day, but if we are doing it in a basement with no windows, we won't ever really know ...

Comment: The 737 Max went straight into the ground twice because "Someone did not do the analysis".

Comment: We have analysis of your feature request: only 1 of 17 users thinks it would improve user experience.

Comment: Zero of which did the analysis.

Comment: Boeing also thought that the 737 Max would not steer itself into the ground.

Comment: Why you are so insistent that **we** have to do the analysis to back up **your** assertion? If you want the research, why not do it yourself?

Comment: Again if SO does not care about user experience then they should not do the analysis.

Comment: yannis, just in case if you didn't notice they already run an [experiment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390178/why-can-i-no-longer-see-that-a-post-has-a-negative-score) for hiding downvotes about 2 months ago (it is referred in linked questions). As far as I can tell results were quite disappointing

Comment: @gnat that experiment is a great resource.  They could also display the count if for example the post receives a 3 negative down votes within 2 minutes.  That filter out the one grouchy person who does not understand the question, from the rest.

Comment: Where is the evidence for the existence of 'grouchy persons who downvote questions that they do not understand'?  Where are these users?  Why would they behave in such an irrational manner instead of just ignoring/skipping the question?

Comment: All SO has to do to answer that is search for all the question that received one down vote with no comment.  Then within 5 minutes the question was answered, accepted, and everyone was happy.  How many question like this exist in the SO database?

Comment: @Ole your query condition would highlight rep-reapers who will copy/paste multi-duped gunge for a few internet points.  Any 'downvoting grouchy users' would be lost in the noise.  Occam suggests to me that those users do not exist and that they are excuses dreamt up to try to shift the blame/responsibility for bad questions away from the askers and on to the curators.

Comment: @MartinJames All SO has to do is first identify the pattern and then look at the posts.  Find 10 cases where it exists and show everyone.  It will be very easy.

Comment: It's also simply natural human behavior to come across something that we may not understand and then down vote it because we don't understand it or we think that it is inadequate or not MVCEish enough.  Most users give something a 2 second scan and then depending on how they feel act.  One third of the US population is diagnosed with mental health issues, so making the argument that reviewers will all be Elon Musk and rational has a few punch holes in it.

Comment: I like the OCCAM reference though.

Comment: https://medium.com/@ole.ersoy/the-power-of-the-simplest-possible-example-8a1e9057821f